# Changing style of Proof

Tags: formatting, theorems, amsthm

I'm using the `\begin{proof}` of the `amsthm` package. And I want to change the style of the `Proof` word that is added in the beginning. By default it is italic, I want to make it bold. How can I do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about:

```
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries Proof}}{*something*}
```

*something* - something to be executed after environment argument is processed (possibly empty).

More here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. I've just changed `*something*` to `\qed`

Comment: As a slight improvement for those who like to put `\begin{proof}[Proof of the Lemma] ... \end{proof}`, you can do `\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{{\bfseries #1.}}{*something*}`.

Comment: if you're using `amsthm`, all these redefinitions are too simple-minded; you will lose the ability to use `\qedhere` to adjust the placement of the "tombstone" if the proof ends with a list or display.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You don't. I just tried, and \qedhere works perfectly with amsthm and the adjustment given by Bruno Le Floch.

Answer (score 30):

If you don't mind changing the name of the environment, just use a variant of the following code. Change `\ttfamily \scshape \large #1 (yes, "#1")` to something more sensible: `#1` denotes the "Proof" word.

```
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \proof[\ttfamily \scshape \large #1 (yes, ``#1'')]%
}{\endproof}

\begin{myproof}
Hi.
\end{myproof}
```

The proof environment takes one argument and puts it in italics (by default this argument is `Proof` in English). Our new environment also takes one argument, denoted `#1` (with the same default), and feeds it to the `proof` environment after transforming it a bit (or a lot). Here I decided to write the "proof" word in typewriter small-caps, large, and I even put it twice: "Proof, (yes, 'Proof')". Anything can be done with it.

If you want to redefine the `proof` environment itself, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldproof\csname\string\proof\endcsname
\let\oldendproof\endproof
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \oldproof[\ttfamily \scshape \large #1 (yes, ``#1'')]%
}{\oldendproof}
\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}[Foobar]
    Some example text.
  \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

When we redefine the `proof` environment, we are in fact defining `\proof` and `\endproof`. The primitive `\let` makes `\oldproof` into an exact copy of what `\\proof` means initially, so that we can use it for defining `\proof`. Otherwise, `\proof` would expand to `\proof[...]`, which would expand to `\proof[...]`, etc, looping forever.

EDIT: revised the last code snippet, which was completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. But the `an_ant` answer with a `\renewenvironment` looks simpler to me.

Comment: `an_ant`'s way has a drawback: the `\qed` symbol won't always be placed properly (AFAIK, the ams packages work hard to do get spacing and everything right). Also, it removes the optional argument. [...] In fact, this can easily be fixed (see my comment on `an_ant`'s answer.

Comment: Your second example (redefining proof) results in "LaTeX Error: Command \proof already defined." And changing it to use \renewenvironment creates an infinite loop and crashes LaTeX due to memory overflow :-(

Comment: @Max Sorry for the delay in fixing that.  My fix is ugly but should now work.

Answer (score 17):

A better and simpler solution is to redefine `\proofname`:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\oldproofname=\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\rm\bf{\oldproofname}}
```

This is better than redefining the `proof` environment because the environment goes to considerable lengths to position the `\qed` mark correctly, and to respect the indentation style used in theorems (which is not necessarily the same as for normal paragraphs).  It also works fine with the `babel` package which is helpful if you work in more than one language, or are writing a style file that might be used with multiple languages.

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764) on the use of old font macros like `\rm` and `\bf`.

Comment: You cannot use `\textit` or `\textbf` because they're block-level and you need the bold effect to propagate beyond the `\oldproofname` (which is 'Proof' in English) so that the full stop is also in bold.  TeX's modal \rm and \bf commands do that.  It might have been better had I used `\upshape\bfseries` instead of `\rm\bf` as they're the LaTeX versions, but to be honest, I don't see a big difference.

Comment: The proposed link(s) provide a reason behind the choice to stick to LaTeX-related commands. It may not be evident from your example, but in general it is a good idea to avoid the two-letter font commands. True, using `\upshape\bfseries` would act as *switches* in analogue to `\rm\bf` compared to macros that gobble their arguments (as does `\textbf` and company). To that extent, you don't need to group `\oldproofname`, since neither `\rm` not `\bf` takes an argument.

Comment: If you redefine `\proofname` only then the dot after proof name will remain non-bold italic.

Comment: I expected to be able to put those commands in the preamble, but when I did, they had no effect. When I moved them to the body of the document (immediately after `\begin{document}`), then everything was fine.

Answer (score 12):

many of the fonts in the ams document classes and amsthm.sty are "frozen", even
though they are changed in publication-specific classes to effect a different style.
for the next upgrade of the ams-latex collection, we are considering assigning
"logical" names to most such fonts, to simplify the ability to make changes such as
the one requested here.  the "proofheadfont" will be among the fonts to be generalized.

Answer (score 7):

If you're able and happy to modify your amsthm.sty, then find the command that begins `\newenvironment{proof}` (close to the end of the file), and change `itshape` to `bfseries`.

Alternatively, just paste the following into the preamble of your document:

`\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname] {\par\pushQED{\qed}\normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother`

Then the proof environment will behave exactly as before in terms of spacing, optional argument, \qedhere and so on, but you'll have bold rather than italic.

Comment: I'd definitely _not_ recommend changing a style file for this.

Comment: Copying this code into the preamble did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution to the same problem.
First, I took the code snippet related to the `proof` environment in `amsthm.sty`:

```tex
‎\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par‎
  ‎\pushQED{\qed}%‎
  ‎\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax‎
  ‎\trivlist‎
  ‎\item[\hskip\labelsep‎
        ‎\itshape‎
    ‎#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces‎
}{%
  ‎\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse‎
}
```

I copied the snippet to the style files of my own document with a little modifications, just as it should have been implemented to allow the customization of "proofname" style:

```tex
‎‎‎‎\makeatletter‎
‎‎\providecommand{‎\proofNameS‎tyle}{‎\itshape‎‎}‎‎
‎\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par‎
  ‎\pushQED{\qed}%‎
  ‎\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax‎
  ‎\trivlist‎
  ‎\item[\hskip\labelsep‎
        ‎\proofNameStyle‎
    ‎#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces‎
}{%
  ‎\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse‎
}‎
‎\makeatother‎
```

‎
Then, the following command in my document styles customizes the style of "proofname" as expected:

```tex
‎‎‎‎\renewcommand‎{‎\proofNameStyle‎}‎{‎‎‎\bfseries}‎
```

You can use this command if you want to have the "proofname" both italic and bold:

```tex
‎‎‎‎\renewcommand‎{‎\proofNameStyle‎}‎{‎‎‎\itshape ‎‎‎\bfseries}‎
```

‎

Comment: I proposed the same idea time ago. I'm still hoping that the AMS will implement it. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477477/4427