# Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, macros, formatting, obsolete

I understand that `\bf` and `\it` are now obsolete in LaTeX and that `\textbf` and `\textit` are proper, as they produce more sophisticated (in particular, cumulative and properly kerned) changes to font style. I have read the [English version of "Obsolete commands and packages", v. 1.8.5.7 of l2tabu, Sec. 2.1](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/) and I understand the rules and their reasons, as well as the several other commands that are affected.

However, I find it convenient to use LaTeX for notetaking during lectures, and in that rushed environment, shortening a command by any number of keystrokes helps keep me from falling behind. `\bf` and its two-letter kin are still very useful to me for that reason, and once a presentation is finished I can go through and replace all appearances of `\bf` et al. with `\textbf` et al.

My question is this: is there a plan eventually to replace the short font style commands like `\bf` with the implementations of `\textbf` etc. some day, or should I expect `\bf` always to remain in existence but obsolete, for reasons of backward compatibility with original TeX? Original TeX has been greatly improved on in countless ways, but in the heat of transcription I sometimes miss its conciseness.

Comment: You can alias the commands, `\let\tt\texttt` and you will be ok.

Comment: Perhaps you could migrate to a markdown format like [multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/)?

Comment: Why don't you use a LaTeX editor that has keyboard shortcut support for the formatting commands?  If you know how to use Emacs (or are willing to learn), AucTeX is best-of-breed, but there are other more GUI-oriented options (Texmaker, to name one) as well.

Comment: @Yiannis: I think you mean `\let\tt\ttfamily`!

Comment: `\tt` has the clear advantage to switch to a fully defined font, which is not achieved by `\ttfamily` but rather by `\normalfont\ttfamily` (as done not by LaTeX format, but by LaTeX standard classes when providing a `\tt` macro; I am skipping here math mode discussion). Why do people hate `\tt` will remain an eternal mystery to me. KOMA-script turned it into an error in recent releases, breaking old, possibly useful packages, now unmaintained, which used it. Is this reasonable? No.

Comment: addition to my comment: `\tt` as I said switches to a fully defined font in Plain TeX (`\tentt` which is `cmtt10`), but the LaTeX article class implementation `\normalfont\ttfamily` (in text mode) does not reset the size. A `\normalsize` is lacking for closer analog to `\tt`. Admittedly it looks it was a reasonable decision to omit this fontsize reset thing.

Comment: A dissenting opinion--swimming against the tide: I fear that the future of LaTeX is being made by typesetting specialists, who don't mind if text is pepped with a 7-character command every time one wants to emphasize a phrase.  However, LaTeX is mostly used by writers, all of whom want nice formatted text, but few of whom are specialists.  I spend a lot of time staring at text files containing my ideas.  I have to be able to read what I wrote before it is formatted.  A three-character `\em` or `\it` is less intrusive than `\textit`.  Sigh.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The simple answer is no, because the new font commands work better for the reasons in the links you cite.

The best way to reduce your typing to customize your editor.  In my editor (TeXShop on a Mac) I have the command `\textbf{}` bound to Command-B, and `\emph{}` to Command-I. (I generally don't use `textit{}`) This makes it simple to use the "new" font commands in my source but with drastically reduced typing.

Most editors should be able to do this sort of shortcut.

Comment: I'd imagine that if we ever succeed in writing LaTeX3 as a stand-alone format, we won't even include `\bf`, _etc_. There's nothing stopping you doing `\let\bf\textbf`, though.

Comment: @Joseph: Shouldn't it be `\let\bf\bfseries`? After all `\bf` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @Martin: From the question, it seemed that the idea was to use `\bf` as a short-hand for `\textbf`, not for `\bfseries`. Hence my suggestion. (I'd say that `\bf` is _not_ a LaTeX command, so it does not have a 'defined' LaTeX syntax. So the OP can do what he likes!)

Comment: @Joseph: Ok, in his own document he can. As long no one still used `\bf` in some package.

Comment: `\textbf` is to make text bold, which is similar to `\textit`. `\emph` is to emphasise text not necessarily with italics as far as I know. I think that, if you use `\emph`, you better define something like `\strong` for strong emphasis instead of using `\textbf`.

Answer (score 33):

EDIT2: There is now a `markdown` package, which can be used with the LuaTeX engine.

Following on the markdown idea mentionned in comments by `@Emre`, it can be coded in LaTeX. For instance, the code below gets `*italics*` and `**bold**` to work (with nesting as well).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\star@out}{%
  \star@ifnext{\bgroup\bfseries\let\star@current\star@inbf\@gobble}%
              {\bgroup\itshape\let\star@current\star@init}}
\newcommand{\star@inbf}{%
  \star@ifnext{\egroup\@gobble}{\bgroup\itshape\let\star@current\star@initbf}}
\newcommand{\star@init}{%
  \star@ifnext{\bgroup\bfseries\let\star@current\star@initbf}{\egroup}}
\newcommand{\star@initbf}{\star@ifnext{\egroup\@gobble}{\egroup}}
\let\star@current\star@out

\newcommand{\star@ifnext}[2]{%
  \def \reserved@a {#1}%
  \def \reserved@b {#2}%
  \futurelet \@let@token \star@ifnext@aux 
}
\begingroup
\catcode`\*=13
\@firstofone{\endgroup
  \newcommand{*}{\star@current}
  \newcommand{\star@ifnext@aux}{%
    \ifx \@let@token *\let \reserved@c \reserved@a 
    \else             \let \reserved@c \reserved@b 
    \fi 
    \reserved@c
  }
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\*=13}


\begin{document}

Hello, *th**i**s* is a **test, *to see* whether** it works.

\end{document}
```

EDIT as per Hendrik Vogt's suggestion. The construction

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\*=13
\@firstofone{\endgroup ... }
```

ensures that every `*` within the argument of `\@firstofone` has catcode `13`. Namely, a group is started, in which `*` are active, then `\@firstofone` does nothing but forces TeX to read its argument, converting characters of the input file to tokens (with catcode fixed, except if someone later uses `\scantokens`), and the group then ends with `\endgroup`. The catcode of `*` is restored, which means that any `*` which is read later (i.e., not those in the argument of `\@firstofone`) will be of catcode `12` (other). The advantage of this construction over doing `` \catcode`=13 `` before and `` \catcode`=12 `` after is that the catcode of `*` keeps whichever value it had, even if it wasn't `12`.

Comment: It would be great to see an explanation what `\@firstofone` does here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Now I remember: This trick reminded me of the `\lccode` trick I saw in several of Phillip Goutet's answers, but it's somewhat different.

Comment: @Hendrik: it is definitely inspired from the `\lccode` trick (which I think I learnt from Philippe Goutet). It is less powerful, though, since that won't work to change the catcode of a letter (except if that letter appears nowhere in control sequences in the argument).

Comment: Surely it would be easier at this stage to just write in markdown and then use e.g. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert it to LaTeX later…

Answer (score 32):

To expand on Alan's good answer (and to reiterate his ‘**no**’) there's another big reason that `\bf` and `\it` are not recommended now: they are short and easy to type, but they do not have semantics. LaTeX attempts to separate content and formatting in its markup, and these font changing commands break such ideals.

In the rough, commands to type often as part of your document should be short and meaningful; commands to define formatting decisions should be long and descriptive.

Answer (score 11):

Following the answer of Bruno, the `wiki` package allow a very simplified entry of
boldface and italics fonts using the Wikipedia syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wiki}
\begin{document}
\wikimarkup
Write in '''bold''', ''italic'' or '''''both'''''.
\end{document}
```

Bold and italics can be nested and even overlapped, so that you can obtain the eqivalent to `\textit{inter\textbf{sec}}\textbf{tion}`
with  `''inter'''sec''tion'''`.

Answer (score 7):

First, regarding the use of the PlainTeX-based font switching commands `\rm`, `\sf`, `\tt`, etc in a LaTeX document: Even though the LaTeX2e kernel does not define these commands, they are in fact still available *if* you use one of the "standard" document classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book` -- or a document class that's based on these three classes. For more on how `\rm`, `\sf`, etc are implemented in the `article`, `report`, and `book` classes see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304312/5001) to the posting [Is there any reason not to use \let to redefine a deprecated control sequence to the currently recommended one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304311/5001)

Second, here's a solution that uses LuaLaTeX to convert some simple markdown-type text formatting "instructions" into LaTeX code. Specifically, text inside matched pairs of `***`, `**`, and `*` characters in a line of input is rendered in ***bold-italics***, **bold**, and *italics*, respectively.

The operation of the Lua function that does the main work can be initiated and terminated via two LaTeX macros named `\MarkdownOn` and `\MarkdownOff`. The Lua function doesn't operate on material contained in `verbatim`-like environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
in_verbatim = false
function markdown ( line ) 
-- don't operate on input if we're in a verbabim-type environment
if string.find ( line , "\\begin{[vV]erbatim}" ) then
  in_verbatim = true
elseif string.find ( line , "\\end{[vV]erbatim}" ) then
  in_verbatim = false
elseif in_verbatim == false then
  line = string.gsub ( line, "%*%*%*(.-)%*%*%*" , "\\textbf{\\textit{%1}}")
  line = string.gsub ( line, "%*%*(.-)%*%*" ,     "\\textbf{%1}")
  line = string.gsub ( line, "%*(.-)%*" ,         "\\textit{%1}" )
end
return line
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\MarkdownOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", markdown, "markdown" )}}
\newcommand\MarkdownOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", "markdown" )}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\MarkdownOn
Lua function \texttt{markdown} turned on:

*italic*, **bold**, ***bold italic***

\bigskip
A line inside a \texttt{verbatim} environment:

\begin{verbatim}
*italic*, **bold**, ***bold italic***
\end{verbatim}

\bigskip
\MarkdownOff
Lua function \texttt{markdown} turned off:

*italic*, **bold**, ***bold italic***
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did the LaTeX kernel *ever* define those commands? As far as I know, `\bf`, `\it` etc. are TeX font switches and nothing to do with LaTeX.

Comment: @cfr - It depends on the version of LaTeX: The LaTeX2.09 kernel -- yes, I'll admit to being old enough to having used LaTeX2.09 for real work ... -- did define `\rm`, `\bf`, etc. In contrast, the LaTeX2e kernel does not. However, the "standard" document classes (but *not* the `memoir` class) designed for LaTeX2e do provide definitions for `\rm`, `\bf` etc, and the definitions are set up to ensure that these font switching macros behave exactly as they would in a Plain-TeX document.

Comment: Fair enough. I never used 2.09. Memoir can define them, I think, if you use the relevant class option, but it will still complain with warnings, I believe.

Comment: @Mico "*the definitions are set up to ensure that these font switching macros behave exactly as they would in a Plain-TeX document. *" is not exactly true. Try in LaTeX `\Large\tt AAA\showoutput`, you will see it uses `\OT1/cmtt/m/n/14.4` and the meaning of the latter is `select font cmtt12 at 14.4pt`, which is not the same as in Plain TeX where `\tt` would also reset the fontsize, as it expands in text mode to the font switch `\tentt` and `\font\tentt=cmtt10 % typewriter` from `plain.tex`.

Comment: @jfbu - I stand corrected!

Comment: :) I could not find my quote of you in your answer but I had picked it from your comment, thus the sin is already attenuated as comments are more volatile :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently:

> scrartcl Error: undefined old font command `\bf'.

After some investigations, I found this on the [tug.org](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2016-July/038985.html) web site:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\makeatother
```

It allows to recover all "old" TeX commands we all like...

Comment: It _allows_, but you shouldn't. The class you are using does not provide them on purpose, because they are obsolete. You really should change to the proper font change commands. Besides, the question does not ask how to get the commands, to your answer misses the point a little.

Comment: see [my comment to OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/will-two-letter-font-style-commands-bf-it-ever-be-resurrected-in-latex#comment1179598_15361)

Comment: Sorry I wanted to answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346870/bf-is-an-undefined-command that has been redirected to this question as a *duplicate*. So it may seems a little bit away from the original question, but it is the only way to answer to the other one (since as a duplicate, its answers are closed...)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is whether there are plans to reintegrate the old TeX commands into LaTeX… You could have left a comment below David Carlisle's answer linking to that TUG site.

Comment: @TeXnician, Phelype Pleinik: The question is "Will two-letter font style commands ever be resurrected in LaTeX?". This answer is basically like "Yes, using these lines of code". Therefore this counts as an answer. Maybe not spot-on, but I really see other LaTeX users which come here and find this useful. Thats what this site is about! If you don't like it, feel free to use your right of downvoting. There is no need to flag this as "not an answer". Even bad answers are answers, and this one is not even THAT bad, just not very recommendable, which can be and already has been stated in a comment!

Comment: @MartinScharrer Okay, so in your view this is an answer. Personally, I would consider the question as posted by the OP more something along the lines of "I know that these should not be used, but I want a canonical answer whether they are “forbidden” forever". For me this answer would be perfectly acceptable if the question was "how". On the other hand, it is no good solution either because the error message shown is issued by KOMA Script which deprecates these commands for a reason but allows to reenable them with the option `enabledeprecatedfontcommands` so without any need for such hacks…

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm not sure if you have received the ping by Martin Scharrer.

Comment: @TeXnician: It's not about the quality of the answer. Moderator flags are not for technical incorrect or just "wrong" answers. The "not an answer" is for posts which do not even try to answer the question: spam posts, follow-up questions or me-too posts, etc. There are not intended for quality control. For this the voting system is in place.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Ah, yes, I just read that on Meta as well. The name is a bit misleading though…