# Passing \newenvironment parameters to the end block?

Tags: environments, parameters

I am attempting to construct a new environment which will allow me to format arbitrary list types (itemize, enumerate, description etc.) with the new environment.  As such I am passing it as a parameter to the new environment but it complains when I attempt the following:

```
\newenvironment{mylist}[1]
{
\begin{#1}
#Environment definition here
}
{\end{#1}}
```

I get the following error:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \endmylist.
>    
>                      1
>   l.15 {\end{#1}}

How can I pass my parameters into the end block?

Comment: The reason why you can't use arguments in the "end" part of the definition of a new environment and some possible solutions are given in [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/3954).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `xparse` package:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mylist}{m}{%
  \begin{#1}%
  % other code
}{%
  \end{#1}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful package. As a side note for everyone who, like me, doesn't know `xparse` the `{m}` parameter is specified just like table columns. The `m` stands for "`m`andatory parameter".

Comment: As of October 2021, loading `xparse` is not needed, as the code has been incorporated in the kernel

Answer (score 1):

The [`environ` package](//ctan.org/pkg/environ) is an alternative way to achieve this, since it negotiates the environment content like a macro (called `\BODY`) and lets you place arguments around it as needed. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,lipsum}

\NewEnviron{myenv}[1]{%
  \textbullet~Some code #1 \textbullet\par% Use argument before \BODY ~ \begin{myenv}
  \BODY \par
  \textbullet~Some code #1 \textbullet% Use argument after \BODY ~ \end{myenv}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]

\begin{myenv}{argument}
  \lipsum[1][2-5]
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[1][6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’d say that `environ` is obsolete