# Problem with newenvironment

Tags: tables, environments, parameters

I'm defining new environment and I'm trying to pass to it two arguments:

```
\newenvironment{ctable}[2]%
{%
\begin{center}%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
}%
{%
    \end{tabular}%
 \captionof{table}{#2}%
\end{center}%
}
```

Problem is with a second parameter (`captionof`), it isn't working. Is there a nice way to make it work? I'm aware that `captionof` could/should be after `\begin{center}` or before it, but I need it to be below the table. In short: first argument defines table, second defines caption of the table.

Thank you.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/8057 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20576/8057 for more background. (We might as well call it a duplicate...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick storing the second parameter as macro and using it in the "end" part of the environment:

```
\newenvironment{ctable}[2]%
{%
  \def\ctablecaption{#2}%
\begin{center}%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
}%
{%
    \end{tabular}%
 \captionof{table}{\ctablecaption}%
\end{center}%
}
```

Comment: Nice trick. `;)`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. `:)`

Answer (score 9):

Using the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package you can avoid the standard trick illustrated in **Heiko**'s answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{ctable}[2]%
{%
\begin{center}%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
    \BODY
    \end{tabular}%
 \captionof{table}{#2}%
\end{center}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ctable}{cc}{test}
test & test
\end{ctable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!, I didn't know about this package, I'll try it. `;)`

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to avoid floating tables, which is quite dangerous. Moreover you lose flexibility. However, if you really want to shoot yourself in the foot `;-)`, here's a possibility: the package `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,capt-of}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ctable}{mm} % two arguments in braces
 {% begin part
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
 }
 {% end part
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{#2}
  \end{center}
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{ctable}{ll}{A meaningful caption\label{tab:foo}}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{ctable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was aware of `xparse` package, just thought to try without it. Thank you egreg. `;)`