# Using parameters in \newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

Is there any way to use parameters of the structure `\newenvironment{example}[]{}{}` after the text between the `\begin{example}` and the `\end{example}`.
For example, how do I write a new environment that takes as a parameter the author of a text and write it AFTER the text written in the environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide some example how you would like to format this? Should the author name be in a new line, right-aligned perhaps? Should the environment be formatted in a special way?

Comment: let's say: text=italics, footnotesized, centered. Author: in a new line,  small caps, footnotesized, right aligned

Comment: Related: [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/5764)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Passing `\newenvironment` parameters to the end block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20576/5764)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** changed the formatting to match specification from comment.

There are two ways to do this, either, with the command `\newenvironment` you can store the argument inside a temporary macro (using `\def` or `\renewcommand`, but initialising it beforehand with `\newcommand` in either case). Or you use `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, in which you can refer to the parameters in the `\end`-part:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand*\exampleARG{}% to assert the name is free
\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {%
    \par\medskip
    \def\exampleARG{#1}%
    \begingroup
      \centering
      \itshape
      \footnotesize
  }
  {%
      \par
    \endgroup
    \leavevmode\hfill\mbox{\textsc{\exampleARG}}\par
    \medskip
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Example}{m}
  {%
    \par\medskip
    \begingroup
      \centering
      \itshape
      \footnotesize
  }
  {%
      \par
    \endgroup
    \leavevmode\hfill\mbox{\textsc{#1}}\par
    \medskip
  }

\usepackage[]{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}{a wise duck}
  \blindduck
\end{example}

\begin{Example}{a wise duck}
  \blindduck
\end{Example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this really solved my problem. I'm really new to LaTeX so I had some trouble understanding everything but I somehow figured it out. However it seems overly complicated to do such thing.

Comment: @cento18 not really, imho. The complication is just for formatting, the key point of using the parameter in the end part is just the `\def\exampleARG{#1}` thingy (or in the `\NewDocumentEnvironment` case straight forward `#1`). The rest in the begin-part is only formatting (with `\begingroup` so it doesn't affect the author), the end part could be done differently (`\begingroup\raggedleft\scshape\exampleARG\par\endgroup`), but that's no big difference, imho (though that would also work for authors needing more than a single line...).