# Setup a newenviroment for figure with includegraphics and caption

Tags: floats, environments

Here is my MWE, I want to 'refactor' the code so that I do not need to write so much when I import source code into my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{foo}
  \end{center}
  \caption{The foo describes the bar}
  \label{img:foo}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Ideally I would prefer to just do:

```
\begin{mygraphic}{r}{0.5\textwidth}{The foo describes the bar}{img:foo}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{foo}
\end{mygraphic}
```

I assume I need to do something like:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mygraphic}[4]
{%begin part
\begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{#2}
  \begin{center}
}
{%end part
  \end{center}
  \caption{#3}
  \label{#4}
\end{wrapfigure}}
\makeatother
```

However that doesn't work. It complains about caption and label parameters, so I moved those up into the begin part but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition doesn't work because you cannot use parameters in the "ending part" of the definition of a new environment; see [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/3954). Known workarounds include using macros to store the parameters in the "beginning part" of the definition, or using the [environ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package or using the [xparse](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package.

In this particular case, taking into account this warning mentioned in the documentation of `wrapfig`:

> If you put a wrapfigure in a parbox or a minipage, or any other type
>   of grouping, the text wrapping should end before the group does.

it seems a better idea to define a command instead of an environment; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% syntax: \mygraphic[options for \includegraphics]{position}{width}{name}{caption}{label}
\newcommand\mygraphic[6][]{%
   \begin{wrapfigure}{#2}{#3}
   \centering\includegraphics[#1]{#4}
   \caption{#5}\label{#6}\end{wrapfigure}}

\begin{document}

\mygraphic[width=.6\linewidth]{r}{0.5\textwidth}{foo}{The foo describes the bar}{img:test}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]