# Argument in the end of an environment trick is not working

Tags: environments

I was trying to define a new environment in which I needed to have an argument in the end code. Thanks to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/31058), I got that it is not possible without a trick. That is why I defined a command in the beginning containing the argument to use it in the end, but in vain... Can someone explain me why and/or fix this?

```
\newenvironment{newappendix}[2]%
{\def\headername{#1}%
\phantomsection%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix \thesection~- #1}%
\label{app:#2}}
{\fancyhead[R]{Appendix \thesection~- \headername}}
```

Without the command `\headername` on the last line it works fine but I need this argument here so... What to do?

**EDIT** Here is a MWE (by uncommenting the last line of the end of the definition of the environment you should get an error...

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[L]{{\bfseries Appendices}}%
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}%

\newenvironment{newappendix}[2]%
{\def\headername{#1}%
\phantomsection%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix \thesection~- #1}%
\label{app:#2}}
{\fancyhead[R]{Appendix \thesection~-}}% \headername}}

\begin{document}

\begin{newappendix}{first}{1}
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=15cm]{test}
\end{newappendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than a code snippet so the problem is reproducible?

Comment: Change `\def\headername{#1}` to `\gdef\headername{#1}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, could you please briefly explain the reason?

Comment: Isn't it easier to use `\rightmark`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That works but why?

Comment: @egreg What do you mean by using `\rightmark`?

Comment: @LudovicC.: The entire environment is grouped, making usage of definitions *outside* of it not possible, unless the definition is made `\global`. Note that when `\fancyhead[R]` is "executed" (during page shipout), the definition of `\headername` is "outside" the environment scope. To that end, `\gdef\headername{...}` makes a `g`lobal `def`inition that spans this scoping restriction.

Comment: @LudovicC. (la)tex headings are designed to use a `\mark` system where the page breaker informs the heading code _automatically_ the first and last `\mark` on the page, marks are typically set by section headings so they can be picked up by the page head. If you set th epage head "by hand" as here it will do the wrong thing if you have multiple sections on a page or if you are unlucky and a page break happens close to a section head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the mark feature of LaTeX and not an environment. Here's how I would do it.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries Appendices}
\fancyhead[R]{Appendix \rightmark}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\newcommand{\newappendix}[1]{%
  \clearpage % or the mark could be wrong
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix \thesection~- #1}%
  \markright{\thesection \ -- #1}%
}
\begin{document}

\newappendix{first}\label{app:1}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=15cm]{test}

\newappendix{second}\label{app:2}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=15cm]{test}

\newappendix{third}\label{app:3}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=15cm]{test}

\newappendix{fourth}\label{app:4}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=15cm]{test}


\end{document}
```