# How to configure/redefine the quotation environment to cite?

Tags: biblatex, quoting

I want to redefine the `quotation` or `quote` environment so that I have a different presentation style, such as big quotes or all italics, right aligned, etc.

I also want to cite the source (a real cite, or authorcite ...).

This is what I have:

```
\renewenvironment{quote} %[1]
{
  {\rightmargin\leftmargin}
  \relax
  {\Large\textbf{``}}
}
{
  {\Large\textbf{''}}
  %\hfill\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}
}
```

My problems:

- `{\rightmargin\leftmargin}` to center in less than full width is not working, I copied this from the original `quote` environment. The `quotation` env. used the `list` environment to do this, but that alters the paragraph spacing too, and I do not want that. What is the right way to define the width I want and where I want to center?
- The commented out parts for the citation itself are not working, I wanted to use this as `\begin{quote}{someBibRef}Some bla bla bla.\end{quote}`
  The argument is being passed correctly and I can print it, but I can not use it with cite commands. The output looks like `##1 [##1]` and the error log says `Illegal parameter number in definition of \endquote }`
- How can I make `\citeauthor` display the author's full name, not just the last?
- I wanted this last part to appear in a newline, at right, I haven't found a way to do this simultaneously.

I am using `biblatex` with biber as backend.

Comment: @cmhughes The tag [tag:quoting] doesn't need an additional tag [tag:environment], same as we don't add [tag:environment] to every question about [tag:align], [tag:itemize] etc.

Comment: I initially used the 'environments' tag because I thought the question had a big part on how to (re)define an environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that redefines the `quote` environment using `NewDocumentEnvironment` from the [`xparse`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xparse) package.

```
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\endoldquote\endquote

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{quote}{m}{%
    \oldquote
    \itshape
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}
    {\Large\textbf{``}}
}
{%
    {\Large\textbf{''}}
    \item[]\mbox{}\hfill\cite{#1}\citeauthor{#1}
    \endoldquote
}
```

It was necessary to use this package because, as noted in [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/why-cant-the-end-code-of-an-environment-contain-an-argument), we can't use `#1` at the end of a regular `latex` environment.

Note that I have used the original definition of the `quote` environment and added the line

```
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}
```

which sets the margin (as you noted, the `quote` environment is defined in terms of a list). I also added

```
    \item[]\mbox{}\hfill\cite{#1}\citeauthor{#1}
```

to the end of the environment to add the citation as you wished. You might need to add some code if you're worried about page breaks in between items.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\let\oldquote\quote
\let\endoldquote\endquote

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{quote}{m}{%
    \oldquote
    \itshape
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}
    {\Large\textbf{``}}
}
{%
    {\Large\textbf{''}}
    \item[]\mbox{}\hfill\cite{#1}\citeauthor{#1}
    \endoldquote
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}{kn:gnus}
    \lipsum[1]
    finishing text
\end{quote}

Now is the time.
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib`

```
@online{kn:gnus,
author= {{David Arnold}},
title= {Writing Scientific Papers in \LaTeX},
url = {http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer covers about everything. I guess the double '{{' is what make the full author's name appear? Also, how can I indent paragraphs? (this is not in the original question)

Comment: @brita_ glad it helped :) have a look at [Indenting a whole paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35934) for the paragraph thing

Answer (score 7):

I would discourage you from redefining the `quote` environment, particularly if you change its syntax to want a mandatory argument.

Since this seems to be used for particular purposes, it's better to define a new environment.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{kn:gnus,
author= {{David Arnold}},
title= {Writing Scientific Papers in \LaTeX},
url = {http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{quoting}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{citequote}{m}
 {%
  \begin{quoting}[indentfirst=false,font=itshape]
  \bigquotes{r}{``}\ignorespaces
 }
 {%
  \unskip\bigquotes{l}{''}%
  \item\relax\hspace*{\fill}\citeauthor{#1}\ \textup{\cite{#1}}%
   \end{quoting}
 }
\newcommand{\bigquotes}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][#1]{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A-\height}{\Large\bfseries#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{citequote}{kn:gnus}
\kant*[2]
And so it ends.
\end{citequote}

Now is the time.
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(I shamelessly used cmhughes reference and structure.)

The `quoting` environment provided by the package with the same name can be easily customized.

Note also that I changed the height of the big quotes; the closing ones would make the leading between the last two lines before the citation too far apart if left as they would be naturally. They are both “hanging”, it's sufficient to remove the `\makebox[0pt]` part to avoid hanging.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have taken the good suggestions of making a new environment instead and on better defining the quotes.