# Mysterious horizontal space in newenvironment

Tags: spacing, environments

The following code defines an environment that offsets text vertically (5pt above and below) and horizontally (2em from the left). When compared to a simple `\hspace{2em}`, however, you can see that the environment introduces mysterious (unwanted) horizontal space.  What is causing this and how can it be eliminated?

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newenvironment{offset}
{\par\vspace{5pt}\hspace{2em}}{\par\vspace{5pt}}

\begin{document}
Surrounding text.
\begin{offset}
Foo
\end{offset}
Surrounding text

\hspace{2em}Foo %for comparison
\end{document}
```

Ps.  I've used `\par` to force a new paragraph in the absence of a carriage return.

Pss.  If my objective with the environment can be realized more elegantly, I'd appreciate the recommendation.

Comment: A "more elegant" way of constructing the environment would probably require some use-case examples.

Comment: why do you have the 2em horizontal space? It just indents the first line?? If you want to indent the entire paragraph use an environment like `quote` if you just want a start of paragraph indent use `\parindent`. Either of these would not start the paragraph prematurely and cause the bad space from the end oof line, adding `\ignorespaces` masks the problem but the reral problem is the apparent mis-use of `\hspace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `\ignorespaces` as part of your "beginning" definition. The spurious space stems from the `\begin{offset}` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newenvironment{offset}
  {\par\vspace{5pt}\hspace{2em}\ignorespaces}
  {\par\vspace{5pt}}

\begin{document}
Surrounding text.
\begin{offset}
Foo
\end{offset}
Surrounding text

\hspace{2em}Foo %for comparison
\end{document}
```

You'll see the space removed as well when you use `\begin{offset}%`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. To your request for use-case examples, I intend to use the environment as a general purpose offset for "small" bits of text, math formulae, tables, pictures, etc..

Comment: You could consider the `quoting` environment, or using `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage).

Comment: When I make the concluding vertical space an argument with `\newenvironment{offset}[1]{\par\vspace{5pt}\hspace{2em}\ignorespaces}{\par\vspace{#1}}`, I get errors with the call 'begin{offset}{5pt}Foo\end{offset}.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @steven_nevets: For this you'll have to see [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/5764)

Comment: Oh the tangled webs we weave...

Comment: I think not having `\hspace` would be better than adding `\ignorespaces` If the environment started in vmode then newlines even blank lines at start of the environment would not be a problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The horizontal offset of 2em is equivalent to the left margin of my custom enumitem list (at each level).  This consistency keeps the document from appearing ragged. Would you instead customize the horizontal indention of the `quote` environment to achieve this end?  If so, how?

Comment: but if the text is more than a line only the first is indented using hspace, I'm trying to work out of you want that (in which case `setlength\parindent}{2em}` is better way to do it or if you intend to indent the whole text, in which case hspace does not work and you want to use a list enviornment with \leftmargin set to 2em

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your point now.  I didn't realize that the `hspace` only indents the first line.  In truth, I'm using the offset primarily as a custom non-centered, single-line `\displaymath` environment.  But there are times that I want to offset non-math material (text blurbs, tables, pictures) by the same indent. So it is a general-purpose offset environment that I'm after.  I think your suggestion to use a list environment is probably the way to go.

Comment: @steven_nevets: `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) is exactly that - a list environment.

Comment: @Werner I'll look into that, but I have to admit that I'm growing fatigued by all of the package extensions that I have to call upon for my homework sheets.  I'd prefer to define my own commands and environments and incorporate them all by way of a personal style file.