# Parameter numbering doesn't work in a \newenvironment footer. How to make it work?

Tags: environments

I try to create a new environment for a monotonously repeating tabular, which has one parameter. This must be at the end of the tabular. I tried this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newenvironment{point}[1]
{
    \begin{tabular}{ @{}p{.4\textwidth}p{.4\textwidth}c@{} }
    \hline
}
{
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{Summary}& #1 point
    \end{tabular}
}
```

but I got `Illegal parameter number in definition of \endpoint.` error. I can't figure out, why is it happen and how to solve it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). | Reason for your issue is that [the end code of an environment cannot contain an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/64454).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments of an environment are only available in the definition of the start code. But you can use a macro to save the content of the argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand*\points{}% <- new macro
\newenvironment{point}[1]
{%
    \renewcommand*\points{#1}% <- save the argument
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{ @{}p{.4\textwidth}p{.4\textwidth}c@{} }
    \hline
}
{%
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{Summary}& \points~point
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{point}{5}
  x&x\\
  y&y\\
\end{point}
\end{document}
```

[image]