# newenvironment not taking input arguments

Tags: macros, environments, optional-arguments

This should be a simple thing, but everywhere I've looked says what I have should work I think. After doing this for a few hours I'm calling it and asking for someone to point out the stupid mistake.

Here's my code:

```
\newenvironment{questions}[1]{
\stepcounter{QuestionGroup}
}
{
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {
    0
    }
    {
    #1
    }{}
}
```

When I try to compile this, it gives me the "Illegal parameter number in definition of \endquestions." And moreover it works just fine if I change all the #1 to some filler content, so it's not registering that the [1] should be an optional argument input.

So... what gives?

Comment: Your issue is discussed here: [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/5764)

Comment: You sir are a life saver. All my googling and I couldn't find that... my google fu is weak this day.