# Is it possible to define a new matrix environment with a parameter function at the end?

Tags: macros, environments

Is it possible to define a new matrix environment with a parameter function at the end?

This is the enviorment I am trying to use

```
\newenvironment{amatrix}[2]{%
  $\left[\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right]}
\stackrel{#2}{\rightarrow}$}
```

So that I can type this simple matrix.

```
\begin{amatrix}{3}{r_1\leftrightarrow r_3}
-R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1 \\
0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
1       &   1   &   -1  &   0       \\
\end{amatrix}
```

and get this result.

[image: What the data should look like?]

I know that I can define the environment and the command separately as

```
\newenvironment{amatrix}[2]{%
  $\left[\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right]}

\newcommand{\arr}{$\stackrel{#2}{\rightarrow}$}
```

then I just need to type

```
\begin{amatrix}{3}
-R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1 \\
0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
1       &   1   &   -1  &   0       \\
\end{amatrix}
\arr{r_1\leftrightarrow r_3}
```

but is it possible to combined this into one environment, and how would I do this?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  if you provide a small compilable example that can be experimented with, i'm sure there is someone here who would be delighted to experiment.

Comment: I'm not sure this idea is good: the arrow belongs logically after the matrix and connects two of them.

Comment: @egreg I am still new to LaTeX and I'm trying to learn the program.  The document I am typing is showing the steps of solving a system of linear equation using a matrix.  I was thinking about combined the matrix and the arrow into one environment to simplify the coding, since I am using this same setup so many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem you're running into here is that the `\end{<env>}` definition of a `\newenvironment{<env>}` that takes arguments does not have access to these arguments by default (see [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/5764)). There are ways around it though...

Here is a suggested interface using [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse). It allows you to specify an *optional* second argument for the `amatrix` construction (since you might not need it at every iteration):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{amatrix}{ m o }
  {
    \left[\begin{array}{ @{} *{#1}{c} | c @{} }
  }{
    \end{array}\right]
    \IfValueT{#2}
      {\xrightarrow{#2}}
  }

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{amatrix}{3}[r_1 \leftrightarrow r_3]
  -R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1 \\
  0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  1       &   1   &   -1  &   0
  \end{amatrix}
  \begin{amatrix}{3}
  -R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1 \\
  0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  1       &   1   &   -1  &   0
  \end{amatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The results look arguably nicer if you replace `\stackrel{#2}{\rightarrow}` by `\xrightarrow{#2}` (requires mathtools).

Comment: @marmot: Awesome suggestion.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for your information.  I am still new to LaTeX and I was not able to get this idea to work.  I just have two questions about your solution.  1) Since this new environment is a matrix would it be a good idea to add '$' to the beginning and end of the environment? Or is there something wrong with this idea? 2) Why did you add '\[' and '\]' just before and after the matrix?

Comment: @JFaris: Adding `$`...`$` inside your definition necessarily puts the environment content inside math mode. That means you can't use it inside another math environment (like `\[`...`\]` or `$`...`$`). For this there is `\ensuremath{`...`}`, but then the `amatrix` environment definition will have to be changed. I usually leave such switches (to math mode) out of the definition, since it encourages you to code relative to the context - insert math mode switches where they're needed so the syntax/context is clear. `\[`...`\]` puts its contents in display math mode without equation numbering.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for clarifying this for me.  It makes sense to leave math mode out of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Werner's nice example and added a few (possibly desirable) options.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{amatrix}{ m d() o d() o D(){r} }
  {
    \left[\begin{array}{ @{} *{#1}{c} | c @{} }
  }{
    \end{array}\right]
    \IfValueT{#3}
      {\xrightarrow{\IfValueT{#2}{#2 \cdot} #6_{#3} 
    \IfValueT{#5}      
      { \IfValueTF{#4}{#4 \cdot}{\leftrightarrow} #6_{#5} } } }
  }

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{amatrix}{3}[1][3]
  -R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1 \\
  0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  1       &   1   &   -1  &   0
  \end{amatrix}
  \begin{amatrix}{3}
  1       &   1   &   -1  &   0       \\
  0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  -R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1
  \end{amatrix}
\]

\[
  \begin{amatrix}{3}(2)[1](+3)[3]
  1       &   1   &   -1  &   0       \\
  0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  -R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1
  \end{amatrix}
  \begin{amatrix}{3}
  1       &    1   &   -1  &   0       \\
  0       &    R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  2-3R_1  & 2+3R_2 &   -2  &  3E_2-3E_1
  \end{amatrix}
\]

\[
  \begin{amatrix}{3}(4)[1]
  -R_1    &   R_2 &   0   &   E_2-E_1 \\
  0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  1       &   1   &   -1  &   0
  \end{amatrix}
  \begin{amatrix}{3}
 -4R_1    &  4R_2 &   0   &   4E_2-4E_1 \\
  0       &   R_2 &   R_3 &   E_2     \\
  1       &   1   &   -1  &   0
  \end{amatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: With your introductions I find that it unfortunately also removes some of the *context* from the row operations. `\begin{amatrix}{3}{2r_1+3r_3}` is far clearer than `\begin{amatrix}{3}(2)[1](+3)[3]`.

Comment: @Werner I completely agree with you, it was just a gimmick.