# Tikz grid in an environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, grids

I would like to create an environment having the following role: create an exercise (called "exo" in the sequel) and a grid with a prescribed number of lines. My environment exo works fine, but not with the grid. I tried

```
\newenvironment{exoQuadrill}[1]%
{\begin{exo}}%
{\end{exo} \smallbreak\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,gray]
\draw(0,0) grid (33.4,#1);
\end{tikzpicture}\medbreak}
```

It doesn't work (error : "illegal parameter number"), but it is if I don't specify the number of lines:

```
\newenvironment{exoQuadrill}[1]%
{\begin{exo}}%
{\end{exo} \smallbreak\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,gray]
\draw(0,0) grid (33.4,13);
\end{tikzpicture}\medbreak}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237006/586

Comment: I closed as duplicate of the mentioned question, let me know if you really disgree with that, though using `xparse` as egreg suggested works fine. (`\usepackage{xparse} \NewDocumentEnvironment{exoQuadrill}{m} {\begin{exo}} {\end{exo} \smallbreak\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,gray] \draw(0,0) grid (33.4,#1); \end{tikzpicture}\medbreak}`)