# How can I make such an environment with '"minted'?

Tags: environments, minted

How can I make such an environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{minted,fancyvrb}
\newenvironment{mycode}[1]{
\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}{bash}}{
    \end{minted}
    \caption{#1}
\end{listing}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mycode}{My title}
        echo $PATH
    \end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{minted,fancyvrb}
\newminted{bash}{}
\newenvironment{mysupercode}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{bashcode}}{\end{bashcode}}
\newenvironment{mycode}[1]{
    \VerbatimEnvironment\begin{listing}\begin{mysupercode}}{
        \end{mysupercode}\caption{#1}\end{listing}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mycode}{My title}
        echo $PATH
    \end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

But got the following error:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \endmycode.
>   \end{mysupercode}\caption{#1}\end{listing}}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can't have parameter substitution (`#1`) in the `\end` part of the environment. You could, in the `\begin` part do `\def\thiscaption{#1}` and then use `\caption{\thiscaption}` later.

Comment: Somewhat special case of [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/why-cant-the-end-code-of-an-environment-contain-an-argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have parameter substitution (`#1`) in the `\end` part of the environment. You could, in the `\begin` part do `\def\mysupercodecaption{#1}` and then use `\caption{\mysupercodecaption}` later, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{minted,fancyvrb}
\newminted{bash}{}
\newenvironment{mysupercode}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{bashcode}}{\end{bashcode}}
\newenvironment{mycode}[1]{%
  \def\mysupercodecaption{#1}%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{listing}
    \begin{mysupercode}%
}{%
    \end{mysupercode}%
    \caption{\mysupercodecaption}%
  \end{listing}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mycode}{My title}
        echo $PATH
    \end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

---

This doesn't work the way you wanted to because the `\newenvironment` command basically replaces this:

```
\newenvironment{mycode}[1]{<begin-part>}{<end-part>}
```

by

```
\newcommand{\mycode}[1]{<begin-part>}
\newcommand{\endmycode}{<end-part>}
```

thus the `\endmycode` macro doesn't take arguments. This is mainly because if the `\endmycode` macro was defined to take an argument, you would have to use it like this:

```
\begin{mycode}
  ...
\end{mycode}{<argument>}
```