# csname in newenviroment

Tags: environments

I defined a newenvironment with this code (sample):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{myEnv}[1][default]
{
   \pushQED{#1}
   \expandafter\csname x#1 \endcsname
}
{    \expandafter\csname endx\popQED \endcsname    }

\newenvironment{xdefault}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnv}
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

I need this for some stuff later to call a specific environment using the argument. But I get the following error in Overleaf:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
               \begingroup 
l.35 \end{myEnv}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
-----------
Extra \endcsname.

\endmyEnv ...after \csname endx\popQED \endcsname 

l.35 \end{myEnv}

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

As far as I can tell, the csname/endcsname's should be correct, I don't see an error, so I have no idea what causes this. When I searched the error I only found topics that were unrealated to my example.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: My guess would be that the `\popQED` within `\csname ... \endcsname` is a bit too much for LaTeX. I presume `\popQED` does not expand to simple text, so LaTeX fails to make sense of it as part of a control sequence name. Maybe you just mean `\csname endx#1\endcsname\popQED`? I'm also not quite sure if the `\expandafter`s are needed and the trailing space after `#1` in `\csname x#1 \endcsname` might be too much. (But this is all speculation without a full example document where I can verify the definitions involved.)

Comment: @moewe Using pushQED was something I found searching for how to pass arguments to the end part. The space after #1 was from searching the error, removing them doesn't change that. moving popQED behind endscname causes the error to go, but then it prints 'default' and doesn't call endxdefault

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think `\popQED` and `\pushQED` can help you here. Try `\def\tssavedarg{#1}` and `\csname endx\tssavedarg\endcsname` instead.

Comment: `\expandafter\csname x` expands `x` which is not expandable, so the `\expandafter ` is doing nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% make sure \tssavedarg is not taken already
\newcommand*{\tssavedarg}{}
\newenvironment{myEnv}[1][default]
  {\def\tssavedarg{#1}%
   \csname x#1\endcsname}
  {\csname endx\tssavedarg\endcsname}

\newenvironment{xdefault}{XX}{YY}

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnv}
A
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

`\pushQED` and `\popQED` are specifically for QED handling in `amsmath` and they seem to implement a full QED stack, which you do not need. In particular `\popQED` does not simply expand to the contents saved with `\pushQED`, so it does not work within `\csname ... \endcsname` as expected.

In your case it is enough to just save the `#1` in a normal macro with `\def` and then retrieve the macro value by calling it.

Related [Why can't the end code of an environment contain an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17036/35864).

The `xparse`/LaTeX3 solution would be

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{O{default}}
  {\csname x#1\endcsname}
  {\csname endx#1\endcsname}
```

or maybe even more `expl3`-y

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{O{default}}
  {\use:c{x#1}}
  {\use:c{endx#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

because `xparse`'s environments can access the arguments even in the end code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will lok into this. Btw could you tell me where you found the doc for pushQED/popQED? I couldn't find one, so I didn't really know, how they worked. Just did what was recommended in a thread I found.

Comment: @ThorstenSchmitz I didn't find a lot about the two. The `amsthm` documentation mentions the two only in a code example. But the source code shows that `\popQED` does not simply expand to the saved test and suggests that the two implement a sort of stack. Where were those commands recommended for the job you had in mind, if I might ask?

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf also has a little bit on the commands and their implementation

Comment: It was in a thread, but I don't remember where exactly. Didn't think I would need to since there was just a recommendation without further information.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see how `\pushQED` and `\popQED` are defined in `amsthm.sty`:

```latex
    274 \DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
    275   \ifmmode \mathqed
    276   \else
    277     \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    278     \quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
    279   \fi
    280 }
    281 \let\QED@stack\@empty
    282 \let\qed@elt\relax
    283 \newcommand{\pushQED}[1]{%
    284   \toks@{\qed@elt{#1}}\@temptokena\expandafter{\QED@stack}%
    285   \xdef\QED@stack{\the\toks@\the\@temptokena}%
    286 }
    287 \newcommand{\popQED}{%
    288   \begingroup\let\qed@elt\popQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax\endgroup
    289 }
    290 \def\popQED@elt#1#2\relax{#1\gdef\QED@stack{#2}}
    291 \newcommand{\qedhere}{%
    292   \begingroup \let\mathqed\math@qedhere
    293     \let\qed@elt\setQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax \endgroup
    294 }
```

The name clearly shows that this has to do with the typesetting of the QED marker in proofs, so I included the definition of `\qed`.

There is a “stack”, actually a macro, called `\QED@stack`, that's initialized to empty.

Suppose we call `\pushQED{foo}` when the stack is empty. Two scratch token registers are set: first `\toks@` is set to `\qed@elt{foo}`, then `\@temptokena` is set to contain the current first level expansion of `\QED@stack` (in this case, nothing). Next, `\QED@stack` is redefined to contain the token lists in the two registers; with e-TeX extensions, this could be achieved with the single instruction

```
\xdef\QED@stack{\unexpanded{\qed@elt{#1}}\unexpanded\expandafter{\QED@stack}}
```

So now `\QED@stack` will expand to `\qed@elt{foo}`. If another `\pushQED{bar}` follows, the expansion would become `\qed@elt{bar}\qed@elt{foo}`. But let's stay with the simple case.

What happens when `\popQED` is called? The instructions at line 288 are executed, namely

```
\begingroup\let\qed@elt\popQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax\endgroup
```

The macro `\qed@elt` (that normally is `\relax`, see line 282) is set to mean `\popQED@elt` *inside a group* and then `\QED@stack\relax\relax` is examined. In your case it is

```
\qed@elt{foo}\relax\relax
```

Since the macro `\qed@elt` has been redefined, this is the same as `\popQED@elt{foo}\relax\relax` and, according to the definition of `\popQED@elt`,

```
#1 <- {foo}
#2 <-
```

and therefore

```
foo\gdef\QED@stack{}\relax
```

would remain in the main token list (the braces are stripped off by rule of TeX). In case `\QED@stack` had been `\qed@elt{bar}\qed@elt{foo}`, we'd have

```
#1 <- {bar}
#2 <- \qed@elt{foo}
```

and `bar\gdef\QED@stack{\qed@elt{foo}}\relax` would be pushed into the main input stream.

Just the fact that the expansion of `\popQED` begins with `\begingroup` disqualifies it from being legal inside `\csname...\endcsname`; moreover assignments cannot be performed in that context, so it's a lost battle to begin with.

The double `\relax` is in case the stack is empty at the time `\popQED` is called, that is without a matching `\pushQED` command.

What's the main usage of the system? The standard `proof` environment in `amsthm.sty` is defined as

```latex
    432 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    433   \pushQED{\qed}%
    434   \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    435   \trivlist
    436   \item[\hskip\labelsep
    437         \itshape
    438     #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
    439 }{%
    440   \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
    441 }
```

The idea is that a subordinate proof environment might define its own tombstone symbol and push it in the stack, so at end environment the right symbol would be used.

---

Can you use stacks for this purpose? Yes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newstack}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_thorsten_#1_stack_seq }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\push}{mm}
 {% #1 is the stack's name, #2 the item to push
  \seq_gpush:cn { g_thorsten_#1_stack_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\pop}{mo}
 {% #1 is the stack's name, #2 what you should do with the top item
  % reinitialize, in case it has been modified
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__thorsten_stack_exec:n \__thorsten_stack_exec_default:n
  \IfValueT{ #2 }
   {
    \cs_set:Nn \__thorsten_stack_exec:n { #2 }
   }
  \seq_gpop:cNTF { g_thorsten_#1_stack_seq } \l__thorsten_stack_item_tl
   {% if the stack is not empty
    \__thorsten_stack_exec:V \l__thorsten_stack_item_tl
   }
   {% if the stack is empty, issue an error
    \__thorsten_stack_exec:n { \STACKEMPTYERROR }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__thorsten_stack_item_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__thorsten_stack_exec_default:n { #1 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \__thorsten_stack_exec:n \__thorsten_stack_exec_default:n
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__thorsten_stack_exec:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newstack{env}

\newenvironment{myEnv}[1][default]
 {%
  \push{env}{#1}%
  \csname x#1\endcsname
 }
 {%
  \pop{env}[\csname endx##1\endcsname]%
 }

\newenvironment{xdefault}{\par start}{finish\par}
\newenvironment{xinner}{\par startinner}{finishinner\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnv}
\begin{myEnv}[inner]
\end{myEnv}
\end{myEnv}

\newstack{foo}

\push{foo}{A}
\push{foo}{B}
\push{foo}{C}

\pop{foo}[@@#1@@]
\pop{foo}[??#1??]
\pop{foo}[!!#1!!]
\pop{foo}[---#1---]

\end{document}
```

The `\push` command takes as arguments the stack's name and the item to push. `\pop` takes as mandatory argument the stack's name and the optional argument is a template for what to do with the popped item (default is to just deliver it) after removing the item from the top of the stack.

Be careful with spaces in your input: `\csname x#1 \endcsname` is not the same as `\csname x#1\endcsname`.

[image]

Since in the last example the `\pop` operation is called on an empty stack, an error is produced

```latex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \STACKEMPTYERROR 

l.69 \pop{foo}[---#1---]
```

Comment: Thanks for that very detailed explanation. For now I will stick to the xparse package, but I'm sure this will be usefull in the future. At the very least it's a great explanation for pushQED/popQED.