# What do \pushQED and \popQED do?

Tags: amsthm, qed

I have seen the commands `\pushQED` and `\popQED` used in quite a few examples, many connected with the `amsthm` `proof` environment, but I cannot find any documentation explaining what they actually do or why you would need them. What do they do?

Comment: Looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491666/250119 has _some_ explanation, but documentation indeed looks sparse. amsclass source code documentation just has [this much explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH2g3.png).

Comment: @user202729 -- While that is the exact description given in `amsclass.pdf`, looking there for where and how the two commands are used is also instructive.  (Briefly, the intent is to make it possible to place a qed symbol at the end of the last line of an equation or a nested list, when that ends a proof, rather than on the next line by itself.)

Answer (score 2):

The basic purpose of `\pushQED` and `\popQED` is to ensure that when `\qedhere` is used, no QED symbol will appear at `\end{proof}`.

This also allows nested proofs, which is why a stack is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{innerproof}{%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}%
  \proof[Inner proof]
}{\endproof}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/endproof/before}{%
  \expandafter\typeout\expandafter{\detokenize\expandafter{\QED@stack}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This is a standard proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
This is a standard proof ending with an equation
\[
1=1. \qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
This proof has inner proofs inside it.

\begin{innerproof}
This has only text.
\end{innerproof}

Some text in between.

\begin{innerproof}
This ends with an equation
\[
0=0. \qedhere
\]
\end{innerproof}

Some final text.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The `\AddToHook` business is just for debugging, so we can see the stack at each call of `\endproof`. In the console (and log file) you'll see

```
\qed@elt {\qed }
\qed@elt {}
\qed@elt {\qed }\qed@elt {\qed }
\qed@elt {}\qed@elt {\qed }
\qed@elt {\qed }
```

This shows that when `\qedhere` is used, the top item in the stack, when `\endproof` is about to be executed, contains `\qed@elt{}`, so no `\qed` command is performed, because `\qedhere` has been found in the same environment. Basically, `\qedhere` replaces `\qed@elt{\qed}` as the top item in the stack with `\qed@elt{}`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a very clearly written example, though your example doesn't use `\pushQED` or `\popQED` anywhere, so I'm still not sure when they're needed.

Comment: @JoelCroteau They're used by `\proof` and `\endproof`. You can use them if you want the same behavior without using the `proof` environment; often it's asked for exercises.