# Can't pass argument to second part of newenvironment

Tags: environments, arguments

This code works:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{testenvironment}[1][]
    {\begin{quote}#1}
    {\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{testenvironment}[testargument]
test text
\end{testenvironment}

\end{document}
```

This code doesn't:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{testenvironment}[1][]
    {\begin{quote}}
    {#1\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{testenvironment}[testargument]
test text
\end{testenvironment}

\end{document}
```

The only difference is whether `#1` is written within the first vs. the second bracket of the `\newenvironment` command.

How do I pass the argument to the second bracket, to the content *after* the input?

Comment: Use \NewDocumentEnvironment, see the xparse docu.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/why-cant-the-end-code-of-an-environment-contain-an-argument

Answer (score 0):

With more recent LaTeX-releases you can use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` instead of `\newenvironment`.
You may need to load the package xparse.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{testenvironment}{O{}}
    {\begin{quote}}
    {#1\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{testenvironment}[testargument]
test text
\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}
test text
\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}[testargumentB]
test text
\end{testenvironment}

\end{document}
```