# Removing extra vertical space in \maketitle with titling package

Tags: spacing, environments, titles, documentclass-writing, titling

Consider the following two LaTeX source files:

First, manually producing a title using a new environment (eww):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\parindent0cm%
\newenvironment*{mytitle}{\begin{LARGE}\bf}{\end{LARGE}\\[1.5ex]}%
\begin{document}
\begin{mytitle}This is a test document\end{mytitle}
\end{document}
```

Secondly, redefining `\maketitle` using the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\parindent0cm%
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{LARGE}\bf}%
\posttitle{\end{LARGE}\\[1.5ex]}%
\preauthor{}%
\postauthor{}%
\predate{}%
\postdate{}%
\title{This is a test document}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Why does the second "proper" solution give substantially more vertical whitespace before the title?  What can I do about it?

[ Context: I am turning a horrible "let's pretend LaTeX is a word processor" TeX template for a conference into a proper class, and I need to match the spacing. ]

Comment: Does just _deleting_ the empty `pre` and `post` commands have an effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `titling` package defines a length `\droptitle` which needs to be set to a negative value to move it up.  Adding

```
\setlength{\droptitle}{-1cm}
```

to your second example will give you the same result.

By the way, you should use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf` (see [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693)) and use `\vspace{1.5ex}` instead of `\\[1.5ex]`