# Text alignment in tabular-environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I would like to align the text within following table to the top and left. I'm pretty new to LaTeX so I have no clue. Sorry, if this questions has been asked already:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% I found this somewhere but don't remember where

\begin{landscape}

\begin{tabular}{C{4cm}C{4cm}C{4cm}C{4cm}}     %<--- damit geht es jetzt auch ;)
\toprule
Cluster 1 & Cluster 2 & Cluster 3 & Cluster 4 \\ 
\midrule
\begin{itemize}
 \item Canada, France, Germany
 \item Austria, Belgium, Netherlands, Switzerland
 \item Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden
 \item Greece, Portugal, Spain
 \item New Zealand
\end{itemize}
 & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Italy, Japan, United Kingdom, United States
\item Denmark, Ireland
\item Estonia, Hungary
\end{itemize}
 & 
\begin{itemize}
 \item Luxembourg
 \item Czech Republic, Slovenia
 \item Australia, Korea, Turkey
\end{itemize}
 & 
\begin{itemize}
 \item Poland, Slovak Republic
 \item Israel
\end{itemize}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I would necessarily put `itemize` environments inside a table, but with the `enumitem` package, it's easy to control the list spacing.  I've also created a column type that sets the text without justification, which is a better for narrow columns like you have, and centred the column headings using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` for each column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for control of list spaceing

% This creates a column type with no text justification
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{tabular}{R{4cm}R{4cm}R{4cm}R{4cm}}     %<--- damit geht es jetzt auch ;)
\toprule
% centre headings using \multicolum{1}{c}{...} for each column
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}
\midrule
\begin{itemize}[nolistsep,leftmargin=*]
 \item Canada, France, Germany
 \item Austria, Belgium, Netherlands, Switzerland
 \item Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden
 \item Greece, Portugal, Spain
 \item New Zealand
\end{itemize}
 & 
\begin{itemize}[nolistsep,leftmargin=*]
\item Italy, Japan, United Kingdom, United States
\item Denmark, Ireland
\item Estonia, Hungary
\end{itemize}
 & 
\begin{itemize}[nolistsep,leftmargin=*]
 \item Luxembourg
 \item Czech Republic, Slovenia
 \item Australia, Korea, Turkey
\end{itemize}
 & 
\begin{itemize}[nolistsep,leftmargin=*]
 \item Poland, Slovak Republic
 \item Israel
\end{itemize}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Many thanks Alan Munn! Your approach helped. However, why wouldn't you use itemize within tabular?

Comment: @John I don't have any compelling reason not to; it just seemed a bit odd to me. I think that the bullets don't do a lot of work for you there, so you could just put each bulleted line as a row of the table instead.  But this particular table looks quite clean, so I don't see any technical reason not to use it.  You might want to centre the column headings. (Use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cluster 1} & ...` for each column of the header row.)

Comment: Many thanks for the multicolumn-tip. Looks much better now! BTW: Each bullet indicates a group of country (e.g. G7, northern European countries, eastern European countries etc.). I could use \item[northern European countries] for example but this takes to much space. Same goes with rows I think. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With a small reworking of the two proposed solutions I think that this result can be achieved:
[image]

How?

1. comment (if needed) \begin{landscape}... \end{landscape}
2. each column has a width of 3 cm (instead of 4 cm)
3. in each column you get a dot-free line with `\item[]`
4. the first row with heads in bold is simply obtained with

\bf Cluster 1 & \bf Cluster 2 & \bf Cluster 3 & \bf Cluster 4 \

Comment: Please be aware that `\bf` is deprecated. Either replace it with `\bfseries` or use `\extbf{Cluster 1}`instead. See also: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144)

Comment: @leandriis the boldface of heads line is only cosmetics! You can avoid it if You want.