# Why does ConTeXt sometimes ignore surrounding font properties?

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv

I am working on a document which contains a wide range of font styles and sizes. I am using commands such as `\ss` to change to sans serif, `\tfa` to set the font size to size "a", and `\bf` to make text boldface. I am also using brackets to define which areas receive which formatting.

I found the behavior is sometimes unpredictable. Here is an example:

```
\starttext
    {\ss
        This is 12pt sans serif text. \crlf
        {\tfc This is 20.7pt sans serif text.} \crlf
        {\bf
            This is 12pt bold sans serif text. \crlf
    {\tfc This is 20.7pt bold sans serif text.} \crlf
    {\tfc \bf This is 20.7pt bold sans serif text.} \crlf
        }
     }
     This is 12pt serif text.
\stoptext
```

In this example, `\ss` from line 2 sets all text within the brackets to sans serif, however, the `\bf` command in line 5 does create boldface text in line 7.

Why is the text on line 7 ignoring the `\bf` command on line 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `\bf` and `\tf` are font alternatives. So, only one can be active at a time. If you just want to scale according to `a`, `b`, `c` values, use:

```
\unprotect
\unexpanded\def\setbodyfontscale#1%
    {\font_helpers_set_current_font_size{#1}\the\everybodyfont}
\protect

\setbodyfontscale{c}
```

Comment: In LaTeX `\bf` is [therefore deprecated](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text) in favour of `\textbf`. Why is there no equivalent in ConTeXt?

Comment: There is: `\bold`. It is equivalent to **both** `\textbf` and `\bfseries`.