# Error while using combine package

Tags: combine

I am using LaTeX `combine` package for combining articles in Mathematics having document class `amsart`, but very time I had a problem with

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Theorem}[section]
```

Can anyone help me to get out of this.

This is using for Main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,colclass=amsart,reqno]{combine}

\usepackage{amsmath,a4,amsfonts,amssymb,enumerate,fleqn,breqn,times}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{keyval}

\title{Proceedings of the ...}

\author{ Editor\thanks{Support ...}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{combine} % use the combine page style
\maketitle % main title

\tableofcontents % main ToC

\clearpage

\begin{papers} 

\begingroup\import{file1}\endgroup % first article, may have own ToC,

\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

For file1 I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath,a4,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,enumerate,fleqn,breqn}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setdescription{leftmargin=0cm,labelindent=0cm}

\mathindent4em

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

\mathsurround1pt

\def\disp{\displaystyle}

\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}

\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}

\pretolerance=5000

\hyphenpenalty=5000

\def\cc#1{\{#1\}}

\def\pp#1{\|#1\|}

\def\ra{\rangle}

\def\la{\langle}

\def\nh{\mathcal{H}}

\def\A{\mathcal{A}}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{\bf Lemma}

\theoremstyle{remark}

\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{\bf Definition}

\newtheorem{observations}[theorem]{\bf Observations}

\newtheorem*{notationn}{\bf Notation}

\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\bf Example}

\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{\bf Remark}

\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{\bf Proposition}

\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{\bf Corollary}

\newtheorem*{noten}{\bf Note}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{FILE 1}

\author{C}

\address{acs} 

\email{acs@gmail.com}

\def\Ker{\mathop{\rm Ker}}

\subjclass[2010]{ xxC40} 

\keywords{asc} 

\thispagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

abs

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The error shows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \setdescription
                   {leftmargin=0cm,labelindent=0cm}
? 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.39 \newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Theorem}[section]

?
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `\bf` but "had a problem" means what??? Did you get an error if so what (exactly) was the message, cut the message from the log file and show us. Please always include a small _complete_ document that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On topic of `\bf`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681

Comment: You had ommited the important part of the error message that says what the error is, I edited your question to add back both error messages (The benefit of having provided an example that reproduces the error:-) The error is that `\setdescription` is not defined That isn't a command I recognise

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves some unknown macro that hasn't been detailed in edits.