# How to have image span two columns without a page break

Tags: floats, floatrow

I'm making a document with two columns; however, I'd like the first page to server as a cover page with a title spanning two columns and a cover image doing the same.  I tried to do it as follows, using `floatrow` to center the spanned image:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\centerline{\Large\bf Project Title}
\medskip
\centerline{\Large\bf Subheader}
\medskip
\centerline{\today}
\bigskip
]

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.jpg}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure*}

\clearpage %to end the page

%other content
\end{document}
```

However, this *always* causes a page break before the `figure*` environment -- I can't get the image to sit on the same page as the title!  Adding a `[h]` or `[H]` tag doesn't seem to work.  What should I do to get the image to stay on the same page as the previous text?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `titlepage` environment

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
{\Large\bfseries Project Title}

\medskip

{\Large\bfseries Subheader}

\medskip

{\today}

%\bigskip

\vfill
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{titlepage}

\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\bfseries` as `\bf` is deprecated and `\centerline` is TeX, use `\centering` in LaTeX. Also, there is no need of `\label` when you don't have a caption.

Comment: And cover page won't need a page number.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about the title page environment -- that's super useful.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `multicols` may be more useful, than basic LaTeX `\twocolumn`. The picture was changed, of course, and reduced to show all on one page (hence also `\clearpage` commented). The rest is unchanged, however many people dislike `\bf` in LaTeX documents. See, e.g. ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text).

```
%\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,landscape]{article}
\documentclass[11pt,landscape]{article}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%\twocolumn[
\centerline{\Large\bf Project Title}
\medskip
\centerline{\Large\bf Subheader}
\medskip
\centerline{\today}
\bigskip
%]

\begin{figure*}[h]
%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{it}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure*}

%\clearpage %to end the page  % Commented to show all on one page - PS



%other content
\begin{multicols}{2}
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
other content other content other content other content other content
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good suggestion -- it makes it way less finicky to do multi-column spanning.