# Theorem-counter starting from 2

Tags: numbering

So, I recently picked up a .tex-template from some website and added some stuff for my own needs. For some reason the counter starts from 2, and I've attempted some counterresets found online without luck.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt} % Customize the height of the header


\setlength\parindent{0pt}



\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\theoremstyle{plain}
 \newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}
 \newtheorem{conjecture}[subsection]{Conjecture}
 \newtheorem{proposition}[subsection]{Proposition}
 \newtheorem{lemma}[subsection]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{corollary}[subsection]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{remark}
 \newtheorem{remarks}[subsection]{Remarks}

\theoremstyle{definition}
 \newtheorem{definition}[subsection]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
 \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}



\title{
\normalfont \normalsize
\textsc{} \\ [25pt]
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
\huge Notes for Some Subject \\
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}

\author{Some Guy}

\date{\normalsize Spring 2015}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Notes for a course in Blabla.
\section{Representations of finite groups}
\subsection{Blah}
% This becomes definition 1.2
\begin{definition} A {\it group}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is because the template asks the theorems to reuse the `subsection` counter for numbering the theorems, and not a general counter for theorems.

Comment: Please always give minimal examples! I needed to install several packages just in order to help here. If you had reduced you code, you would have found the culprit line in a glance. (just as advice for the future)

Comment: I will keep that in mind @LaRiFaRi, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to write

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]
```

and not

```
\newtheorem{definition}[subsection]{Definition}
```

In your declaration you are letting the `definition` environment share the same counter as `\subsection`.

Instead, in the correct way, you are letting the `definition` counter count *within* the counter `subsection`.

As a side note, never use `\it` in a LaTeX document, but `\textit` or `\itshape`. See for example ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/27635) for reference.

Comment: not explicit here, but after you redefine `definition`, if you want all your theorem-class objects to share the same counter, you should now redefine *them* to use the `definition` counter, not `subsection`.  for example, `\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}`.  however, since `theorem` comes first, if all these objects are to share the same counter, it would be better to use `theorem` as the "master".

Comment: Yes, I took note of that and fixed it accordingly. Thanks.