# Suppress Bibliography number in Table of Contents

Tags: bibliographies, tocbibind

i want to suppress the item number of bibliography in the Table of contents. Searched a lot but could not find any relevant and easy fix for it. i use the following code.

```
// preambles
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\SOME MORE PACKAGES
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}


// main.tex file
\input{chap1.tex}
\input{chap2.tex}
\input{bib.tex}


 // bib.tex file
 \titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf \huge} 
 \begin{thebibliography}{99} 
    \bibitem{asdf}  
       X Y Z.
    \bibitem
       A B C
 \end{thebibliography}
```

Current output

```
4 Conclusions ..... 30
5 Bibliography      32
Appendices          40
...
```

Expected output

```
4 Conclusions ..... 30
Bibliography        32
Appendices          40
...
```

Please suggest. I use `\input{bib}` for inserting my bibliography and i dont have the time fix it using `\bibliography` command. Found a lot of solutions. But wasnt able to incorporate in my current latex code

Note:
I managed to remove the chapter number in the Bibliography section using the `\titleformat{...}` line. But I am not able to remove it from Table of contents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have to do is to simply remove the option `numbib` when loading `tocbibind`, so write

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

If you use the `numbib` option, you are telling LaTeX that you want a **numbered** bibliography...

Note that if you do that, you don't even need the line

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf \huge}
```

in your `.bib` file.

MWE (just to show that it works):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\nocite{*}
 \begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{asdf}
       X Y Z.
    \bibitem
       A B C
 \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

and the bibliography

[image]

As a side note, never use `\bf` in a LaTeX document, but `\textbf` or `\bfseries`. See for example ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/27635) for reference.

Comment: i feel really silly. should have understood first instead of just using the solution from other sources!

Comment: @Pogo Don't feel silly. Everyone can make mistakes ;-)