# Can someone walk me through how this command works?

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I am trying to make it so that my chapters aren't labelled as 'chapter 1', 'chapter 2' etc. I just want it to have the number, with no 'chapter'. I want the word 'chapter' gone. A quick Google search showed me how to accomplish this with the `titlesec`  package, namely

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
```

Which works for me. However, I don't like just using code without understanding it, can someone tell me what this means? I tried to read through the [documentation](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) but I had trouble understanding why that code above results in omission of 'chapter #' before chapters.

Comment: The `titlesec` documentation is not clearly laid out, unfortunately. But here the answer is pretty simple: The first set of empty braces effectly tells `titlesec` to have no "format" (in the sense meant by the package); the next empty braces do the same for "label". Also, since you are using LaTeX, use `\bfseries`, not `\bf`.

Comment: A complete guide would require rewriting the manual, which is not the object of this site. Can you narrow your request?

Comment: Sure, I was only really curious about this command in particular.

Comment: ^^^ I'm pretty new to LaTeX, what does no label imply? Is that why LaTeX doesn't add the heading?

Comment: Since you used an empty third argument, no label is used; in particular, no string "Chapter" (or "Appendix") will be used for the titles and no counter will appear; notice, however, that the counter won't print in the title but it is still there (it will be show in The ToC, for example).

Comment: @PratikSamant I added an answer below, let me know if you want some additional explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Since you used an empty third argument, no label is used; in particular, no string "Chapter" (or "Appendix") will be used for the chapter headings and no counter will appear; notice, however, that the counter won't print in the title but "it is still there" (it will be show in The ToC, for example).

No optional first argument was also used in your definition, so the `<shape>` will default to `hang`, which is the shape used by section headings in standard classes.

In your description you said that you only wanted to suppress the string "Chapter" (or "Appendix") but keeping the numbering, so a better option would be to use something like

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\thechapter}
  {0.5em}
  {}
```

Notice that I added `\thechapter` in the third mandatory argument, so the counter will be typeset and also I moved `\bfseries\LARGE` from the fifth mandatory argument to the second one; in this way the formatting will affect both the label (the counter, in this case) and the title; with your settings (used in the fifth argument) it would only affect the title but not the label.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\thechapter}
  {0.5em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
Some test text

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As a side note, `\bf` is a TeX command which shouldn't be used in LaTeX documents; use `\bfseries` instead in LaTeX2e documents.

The documentation of titlesec explains, in page 4, the general syntax and the meaning for the arguments of `\titleformat`. I see no point in repeating here what appears there.

Answer (score 3):

Right as I start this answer, I see Gonzalo's reference to page 4 of the documentation, which I was about to repeat and annotate here. Oh, well.

Your found code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
```

From page 4 of [the `titlesec` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf):

```
\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]
```

The optional arguments `shape` and `after-code` were omitted from your example, so you've effectively run

```
\titleformat{command}{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}
```

with `command` of `chapter`, `format` and `label` empty, `sep` of `0em`, and `before-code` of `\bf\LARGE` (which should be `\bfseries\LARGE` [since around 1994](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text)).

- `format` corresponds to commands used to format the entire division. In your case, it's empty, or the `\bfseries\LARGE` from `before-code` could be moved there.
- `label` corresponds to commands typeset the division label and number. Yours is empty to suppress the label and number, but you could use any macros with `\titlechaptername`, `\thechapter`, or other commands or text.
- `sep` is the separation between the document division label and the document division title. In your case, `0em` keeps it aligned with the left margin of the body text. Other chapter shapes may use this to control the vertical space between the label and the title.
- `before-code` is code preceding your division title. Yours is `\bf\LARGE`, but it could include decorative rules, vertical spaces, or other commands. It could also be empty if you put your format commands in the `format` parameter instead.