# Font markup issues (\textbf \emph \textit not working)

Tags: fonts, xetex, font-encodings

I seem to have an issue in using many of text markings in my document (**\textbf{} \emph{} \textit{}** don't add any effect to text, but i.e. \sout works).

There's a few relevant compile warning messages, such as:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/cmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 926.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/ppl/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 1.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/ppl/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 122.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/ppl/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 136.
```

-

```
Package scrextend Warning: This package was made to extend other classes but
(scrextend)                KOMA-Script classes by some features of the
(scrextend)                KOMA-Script classes.
(scrextend)                It should never be used with a KOMA-Script class.
(scrextend)                Loading of the package will be aborted.
```

Surprisingly, i also get multiple \bf usage warnings even though i don't directly (or at all as far as i'm aware) call the command:

```
Class scrbook Warning: Usage of deprecated font command `\bf'!
(scrbook)              You should note, that in 1994 font command `\bf' has
(scrbook)              been defined for compatiblitiy to Script 2.0 only.
(scrbook)              Now, after two decades of LaTeX2e and NFSS2, you
(scrbook)              shouldn't use such commands any longer and within
(scrbook)              KOMA-Script usage of `\bf' is definitely deprecated.
(scrbook)              See `fntguide.pdf' for more information about
(scrbook)              recommended font commands.
(scrbook)              Note also, that KOMA-Script will remove the definition
(scrbook)              of `\bf' anytime until release of about version 3.20.
(scrbook)              But for now, KOMA-Script will replace deprecated `\bf'
(scrbook)              by `\normalfont \bfseries ' on input line 10.
```

Similar reports ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370294/textbf-texttt-textit-not-working), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912243/font-shape-undefined-with-latex-twentysecondcv-cls)) specifying [T1] for **fontenc** package, but that did not help. **lmodern** package as suggested ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247443/issues-with-nesting-textbf-and-textit)) also did not solve the issue.

Any suggestions?

---

**TeX distribution:**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.6.26)
```

**File list:**

```
     scrbook.cls    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
nextpage.sty    2009/09/03 v1.1a additional page commands
fontspec.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3unicode-data.def    2014/08/12 v5276 L3 Unicode data
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
  xparse.sty    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fontspec-xetex.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-xetex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to xetex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
pstricks.tex    2014/08/27 v2.57 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2014/08/27 v2.57 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pst-tree.sty    2009/01/25 package wrapper for pst-tree.tex
pst-tree.tex    2011/02/28 1.12 `pst-tree' (tvz,hv)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2011/02/28 1.12 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
textgreek.sty    2011/10/09 v0.7 Greek symbols in text
  lgrenc.def    2013/12/02 v0.11.2 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
greek-fontenc.def    2013/11/28 v0.11 Common Greek font encoding definitions
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
tabularx.sty    2014/10/28 v2.10 `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
    tabu.sty    2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
pdflscape.sty    2008/08/11 v0.10 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
adjustbox.sty    2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-
ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-xetex.def    2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for xetex
ifoddpage.sty    2011/09/13 v1.0 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
changepage.sty    2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
 ngerman.ldf    2013/12/13 v2.7 German support for babel (new orthography)
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
wallpaper.sty    2005/01/18, v1.01 easy wallpaper formatting (MHFW)
 eso-pic.sty    2013/10/06 v2.0d eso-pic (RN)
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
multicol.sty    2014/10/28 v1.8i multicolumn formatting (FMi)
 chemfig.sty    2013/11/28 v1.0h Draw molecule with an easy syntax
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
multirow.sty    
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environm
ent
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
algpseudocode.sty    
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
./style/thesis_style.sty
./style/shortcut_defs.sty
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
fancybox.sty    2010/05/15 1.4
fancyhdr.sty    
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2011/12/02 v1.10 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
scrextend.sty    
csquotes.sty    2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
csquotes.def    2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
csquotes.cfg    
mathpazo.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
glossaries.sty    2014/09/01 v4.11 (NLCT)
mfirstuc.sty    2014/07/30 v1.09 (NLCT)
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
    xfor.sty    2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
datatool-base.sty    2014/06/10 v2.22 (NLCT)
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
datatool-fp.sty    2013/08/29 v2.17 (NLCT)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
glossaries-compatible-307.sty    2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
glossary-hypernav.sty    2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
glossary-list.sty    2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
glossary-long.sty    2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
glossary-super.sty    2013/11/14 v4.0 (NLCT)
supertabular.sty    2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
glossary-tree.sty    2014/08/27 v4.10 (NLCT)
glossary-longragged.sty    2014/07/30 v4.08 (NLCT)
./style/thesis_glossary.sty
quotchap.sty    2012/10/20 v1.1 Decorative Chapter Headings with Quotes
  thumbs.sty    2014/03/09 v1.0q Thumb marks and overview page(s) (HMM)
 picture.sty    2009/10/11 v1.3 Dimens for picture macros (HO)
alphalph.sty    2011/05/13 v2.4 Convert numbers to letters (HO)
pageslts.sty    2014/01/19 v1.2c Refers to special pages' numbers/names (HMM)
undolabl.sty    2012/01/01 v1.0k Overriding labels (HMM)
pagecolor.sty    2012/02/23 v1.0e Provides thepagecolor (HMM)
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
ltcaption.sty    2013/02/03 v1.3-62 longtable captions (AR)
subcaption.sty    2013/02/03 v1.1-62 Sub-captions (AR)
tocstyle.sty    2013/08/11 v0.2e-alpha LaTeX2e KOMA-Script package (versatile t
oc styles)
biblatex.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  blx-dm.def
authoryear.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authoryear.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authoryear.cbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
tex/commands.tex
  german.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ngerman.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 english.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
american.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
  lgrcmr.fd    2013/09/01 v1.0 Greek European Computer Regular
  mt-ppl.cfg    2005/11/16 v1.6 microtype config. file: Palatino (RS)
thesis_main.out
thesis_main.out
glossaries-dictionary-English.dict    
  ot1ppl.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ppl.
 omlzplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OML/zplm.
 omszplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMS/zplm.
 omxzplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMX/zplm.
  mt-msa.cfg    2006/02/04 v1.1 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (a) (RS)
  mt-msb.cfg    2005/06/01 v1.0 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (b) (RS)
 ot1zplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OT1/zplm.
thesis_main.bbl
se-ascii-print.def    2011/12/02 v1.10 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
   t1pag.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pag.
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without having your code it's hard to help. But you should do as the warning suggest: do not load `scrextend` (you are using a KOMA class). Furthermore, you seem to use XeTeX and load fontspec, so are you loading fonts the fontspec way?

Comment: Regarding using code snippet: my .tex header was quite big because of the many packages and commands, but i guess i still should have - my bad.
@ TeXnician: i removed scrextend, i don't quite get what you mean by the "fontspec way". Anyway, switching mathpazo and fontspec helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have, among many other packages (do you really need all of them?),

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

abc \textbf{abc} \textit{abc} \emph{abc}

\end{document}
```

which writes in the log file

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/ppl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/ppl/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 9.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/ppl/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 9.
```

and the consequence is using just upright medium Latin Modern Roman.

The order should be reversed, because otherwise `mathpazo` would choose text fonts not compatible with the EU1 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % For a Palatino text font

\begin{document}

abc \textbf{abc} \textit{abc} \emph{abc} $abc$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should also try and update your TeX system: TeX Live 2015 is three years behind the current release.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me.
I am using a template with many packages because it is for a dissertation :) But you're right, i might not be needing all of them, i guess i should follow the advice here to remove some:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91228/170294