# How do I change the style of a longtable caption?

Tags: longtable

I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|} 
\caption{A caption.}\label{tab1} \\ \hline
1 & 2 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

How can I get the caption to look like

```
{\bfseries Table 1.} {\itshape A caption.}
```

(so, "Table 1." in bold and "A caption." in italic)?

Even better, could I get `{\bfseries Table 1}` on one line, `{\itshape A caption.}` on the next line, and both lines centered?

(Edited to replace deprecated commands.)

Comment: BTW: You should not use \bf and \it in modern LaTeX document. It's a deprecated command, it should not be used for multiple reasons - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text

Comment: Okay, I've replaced those commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `caption` package to do so. Then use `captionsetup` to format the caption to your likings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\captionsetup[longtable]{labelfont=bf,textfont=it,labelsep=newline}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|} 
\caption{A caption.}\label{tab1} \\ \hline
1 & 2 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could anyone say how to do it without the `caption` package? With the actual document class I'm using, the `caption` package tends to cause trouble.

Comment: Can I ask what problems does `caption` package causes? It may be easier and cleaner to resolve those.

Answer (score 3):

Per the query you left on @Kiraa's answer, here's a solution that modifies the macro `\LT@makecaption` of the `longtable` package directly. The solution uses the `\patchcmd` macro of the `etoolbox` package to perform the required surgery on the `\LT@makecaption` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\LT@makecaption}%
   {\@tempboxa{#1{#2: }#3}}
   {\@tempboxa{#1{\textbf{#2. }}\itshape #3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\LT@makecaption}%
   {#1{#2: }#3}
   {#1\textbf{#2. }{\itshape #3}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|} 
\caption{A caption.} \label{tab1}  \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\ \hline
3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

To get a linebreak after the `Table <x>` part, you could use the following code (to be inserted in the preamble in lieu of the patch code shown above):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,ragged2e}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\LT@makecaption}%
   {\@tempboxa{#1{#2: }#3}}
   {\@tempboxa{#1{\textbf{#2.\ }}\itshape #3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\LT@makecaption}%
   {#1{#2: }#3}
   {\Centering #1\textbf{#2.}\par{\itshape #3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\LT@makecaption}%
   {\hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}}
   {\Centering #1\textbf{#2.}\par{\itshape #3}}{}{}
\makeatother
```