# problem formatting longtable caption to match normal table

Tags: captions, longtable

This is driving me mad, so hopefully someone can put me out of my misery.  I can't seem to match the caption formatting of a 'normal' table with that of the longtable.  The issue i have is using the ieeeaccess.cls [file](https://template-selector.ieee.org/api/ieee-template-selector/template/541/download) (or so i believe).  From what i understand longtable should format the caption with the same format as the article class but it seems to revert back to the default.
The MWE code below is my example.  I would like the same font/format shown in Table 1 to be replicated in Table 2 at the top of the table and across the page span.  I have tried to carve out the code that formats the captions from the cls file (described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/formatting-captions-in-longtable-tables?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but it doesn't want to work with me.  I also tried replicating with [captionsetup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258098/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-a-longtable-caption) but i couldn't get this to work either.  Any suggestions?  Is there something simple that i am missing?  How do i force longtable to use the caption format from the class?  Or force it to use the caption formatting from another Table?

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Normal Table\ref{tab:table1} and long Table\ref{tab:longtable}

\begin{table} [h]
\caption{first caption}\label{tab:table1}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{l l} 
 \hline
 \textbf{H1} & \textbf{H2} \\ 
 \hline
 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\onecolumn

\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\caption{A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable}\label{tab:longtable}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
% \multicolumn{4}{c}% 
\caption[]{A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot \hline
\endlastfoot \hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\twocolumn
\EOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Longtable uses a custom caption.  It might be possible to modify it to match IEEEtran.

Comment: I can't find how to download ieeaccess.doc.  It appears to only be available through overleaf.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  The ieeeaccess.cls is available through the link i embedded above.  The format of the manuscript has more color and embedded graphics than other IEEE templates, which is why it isn't a very clean way of posting here and asking for assistance.

I have implemented your solution below.  I can probably live without the Table caption appearing on every page.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to simply add a normal table caption before the longtable.  I don't know what IEEE will think of a "Continued" caption.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Normal Table\ref{tab:table1} and long Table\ref{tab:longtable}

\begin{table} [h]
\caption{first caption}\label{tab:table1}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{l l} 
 \hline
 \textbf{H1} & \textbf{H2} \\ 
 \hline
 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\onecolumn
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable}
\label{tab:longtable}
\end{table}
%
\vskip-\intextsep
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
% \multicolumn{4}{c}% 
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot \hline
\endlastfoot \hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\twocolumn

\end{document}
```

---

This version modifies the longtable caption format.  Only the firsthead caption appears in the `\listoftables`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
    \centering #1{#2\\}#3%
    \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip}%
  \hss}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Normal Table\ref{tab:table1} and long Table\ref{tab:longtable}

\begin{table} [h]
\caption{first caption}\label{tab:table1}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{l l} 
 \hline
 \textbf{H1} & \textbf{H2} \\ 
 \hline
 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\caption{A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable}
\label{tab:longtable}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
% \multicolumn{4}{c}% 
\caption[]{A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable A simple longtable}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot \hline
\endlastfoot \hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\twocolumn

\end{document}
```