# LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end. with \maketitle

Tags: errors, titles, report

I'm begginer in Latex and I get this error when I compile my file

```
LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

following is the code that I used :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \input{style/packages.tex}
  \input{style/style.tex}
  \input{title/title.tex}

  \begin{document}
     \pagestyle{fancy}
     \maketitle
     \newpage
     \input{body/pages/remerciements.tex} \newpage
     \input{body/pages/abstract-fr.tex} \newpage
     \input{body/pages/abstract-en.tex} \newpage
     \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} 
     \tableofcontents \newpage
     \listoffigures
     \listoftables \newpage
     \input{body/pages/titre1/titre1.tex} \newpage
     \input{body/pages/titre2/titre2.tex} \newpage
     \input{body/pages/titre3/titre3.tex}   \newpage
     \input{body/pages/titre4/titre4.tex}   \newpage
     \input{body/pages/titre5/titre5.tex}   \newpage
     \input{body/pages/conclusion.tex} \newpage
     \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
     \bibliography{bibliografie}  \newpage
     \appendix
     \input{appendix/titreA.tex}
  \end{document}
```

This is the content of "title.tex"

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=7.2cm]{title/images/logo_entreprise.png}
        \hspace{\stretch{1}}
        \includegraphics[width=7.2cm]{title/images/logo_centrale.png}



\vspace{\stretch{0.5}}

      \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
                Université Pierre et Marie Curie        & \NomEntreprise                \\
                TFE \@date                          & Orsay         \\
        \end{tabular*}

\vspace{\stretch{1.5}}

    {\large \bf Rapport Final de Travail de Fin d'études \\}
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\LARGE \bf \@title\\}
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\large \it \@author\\}

  \vspace{\stretch{2}}
  \\
  \includegraphics[width=8cm, height=5cm]{title/images/Encryption.png}
  \vspace{\stretch{2}}

      \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{|l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r|}
            \hline
                Tuteurs :                       & Option : (sigle développé)    \\
                &\\
                \textit{ECL} :              &                                                       \\
                Nom, Prénom Tuteur 1    & Filière : (sigle développé)   \\
                Nom, Prénom Tuteur 2    &                                                       \\
                &\\
                \textit{Entreprise} :   &                                                       \\      
                Nom, Prénom Tuteur 1    & Métier : (sigle développé)        \\
                Nom, Prénom Tuteur 2    &                                                       \\  
            \hline
        \end{tabular*}


\end{center}\par 

\end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}

%  \global\let\thanks\relax
%  \global\let\maketitle\relax
%  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
%  \global\let\@author\@empty
%  \global\let\@date\@empty
%  \global\let\@title\@empty
%  \global\let\title\relax
%  \global\let\author\relax
%  \global\let\date\relax
%  \global\let\and\relax
}


\makeatother
```

Can someone tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: Welcome, we can not help you with that as you are not showing us anything. Please make your post self-contained. Say, add any information (package...) which is needed in order to compile your document. We can not guess, what `\input{title/title.tex}` contains and even less, if it does matter here. Try to minimize as much as you can. Most probably, you will find the culprit command by your self.

Comment: Also, see [this site](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-noline.html) to read more about _when_ such errors are raised.

Comment: I eddited the post, I put the content of "title.tex"

Comment: @HakimBenyoucef Thanks. Still far away from minimal, but you got your answer. Off-topic: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\\`  here

```
\vspace{\stretch{2}}
\\
```

is spurious and will always generate this error, simply delete it.

Note also

```
{\LARGE \bf \@title\\}
```

should be

```
{\normalfont\LARGE \bfseries \@title\par}
```

so that the title is set with a baseline spacing appropriate for the size of the text.

Comment: \bfseries, maybe?

Comment: When I compile title.tex alone I get the following error :
! LaTeX Error: \maketitle undefined

Comment: @HakimBenyoucef that is expected, the file is designed to change the definitions from their otiginal values. It should be input into the preamble of a document as you show. It is not itself a document

Comment: @Bernard probably not here. You could use `\normalfont\bfseries` but `\bf` comes to the same thing as you know it is an `article` class document. Headings and titles typically want a fixed font, not pick up the current font as `\bfseries` does.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I didn't know that. Thanks, I've learnt something :o)