# Defining and expanding macros In loops

Tags: macros, expansion, foreach

I want to define and expand macros in a `\foreach` loop. The names of the macros depend on the iteration step. The macros I define are interpreted as strings rather than sets of numbers that I actually want them to be. Here is a minimal example that illustrates the issues more precisely.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\Stage{One,Two}
\newcommand\SubStageOne{2,3,4,6}
\newcommand\SubStageTwo{6,7,8}
\newcommand{\CurrentSubStage}{} % will be defined in each stage loop

\begin{document}
%
\foreach \stage in \Stage {
%
\renewcommand{\CurrentSubStage}{ \expandafter\csname SubStage\stage \endcsname }
%
The Macro replacement of {\tt CurrentSubStage} looks the same as Macro replacement of {\tt SubStage\stage}:
%
\begin{center}
\CurrentSubStage\ is the same as \expandafter\csname SubStage\stage \endcsname .
\end{center}
%
But really they are different: Consider first the output from looping over {\tt CurrentSubStage}:
\begin{itemize}
\foreach [count=\ii] \substage in \CurrentSubStage {
\item Substage number \ii\ is \substage \\
}
\end{itemize}
%
and then this output from looping over {\tt SubStageOne}:
%
\begin{itemize}
\foreach [count=\ii] \substage in \SubStageOne {
\item Substage number \ii\ is \substage
}
\end{itemize}
}
%
%
In the second \verb|\stage| iteration, i.e. ``Two'', I want to loop over \verb|\SubStageTwo| as in the \verb|\SubStageOne| that creates four rather than one item. But I do not know how to to call \verb|\Substage\stage| (This is why I created \verb|\CurrentSubStage|). My questions:
\begin{enumerate}
\item How can I define macro \verb|\CurrentSubStage| such that it does not treat the set of numbers as a single string so that the corresponding \verb|\substage| loop gives an iteration for each number?
\item Is there a possibility to do something like:\\ \verb|\foreach [count=\ii] \substage in \SubStage\stage { ...|?
\item I need to define an ``output'' macro at the end of each \verb|\stage| iteration: Something like \verb|\newcommand{\SubStageOutputOne}| in iteration One and \verb|\newcommand{\SubStageTwoOutput}| in iteration Two. (In my application, this output is a permutation of the set |\CurrentSubStage|. I want to ``save'' this permutation in a macro and call it later, at the end of the document.) In short, how can I include something like \verb|\newcommand{\SubStageOutput\stage}| at the end of each \verb|\stage| loop?
\end{enumerate}
%
[Final note: For my actual purpose, the set \verb|\Stage| contains 6 elements and each \verb|\SubStage| set contains between 3 and 10 elements each.]
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic:`\tt` is a TeX command which shouldn't be used with LaTeX. Use `\texttt` instead please

Comment: You want something like `\edef\CurrentSubStage{\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname SubStage\stage\endcsname}}` (BTW: the `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\csname SubStage\stage \endcsname` is completely useless: it tries to expand `S` before `\csname`)

Comment: Thanks, Clemens, can you explain the individual steps to me? Or provide useful links?

Comment: @clemens An answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like

```
\edef\CurrentSubStage{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  {\csname SubStage\stage\endcsname}%
}
```

That is, you need to expand to the value in `\csname SubStage\stage\endcsname`. `\edef` is a TeX command which completely expands everything in the macro definition before assigning it the the macro it defines. In your example actually

```
\edef\CurrentSubStage{\csname SubStage\stage\endcsname}
```

would suffice but the first version is a bit safer. How does it work? Expanding `\unexpanded` starts expanding what comes next up to the first opening brace. The first `\expandafter` expands the third `\expandafter` which expands `\csname`. So after one expansion cycle we get:

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{\SubStageOne}
```

Now the remaining `\expandafter` expands `\SubStageOne` and we get:

```
\unexpanded{2,3,4,6}
```

The `\unexpanded` then prevents further expansion in the `\edef` so `\CurrentSubStage` becomes `2,3,4,6`. (Analoguous for the second step of the loop.)

---

Remarks:

- `\tt` is not really recommended in LaTeX. Better is to use `\ttfamiy` or in this case `\texttt{...}`, see ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681) for reference.
- the `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\csname SubStage\stage \endcsname` in your code is completely useless: it tries to expand `S` before `\csname` but `S` is not expandable.

---

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\Stage{One,Two}
\newcommand\SubStageOne{2,3,4,6}
\newcommand\SubStageTwo{6,7,8}
\newcommand{\CurrentSubStage}{} % will be defined in each stage loop

\begin{document}

\foreach \stage in \Stage {
  \edef\CurrentSubStage{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    {\csname SubStage\stage\endcsname}%
  }%
  The Macro replacement of \texttt{CurrentSubStage} looks the same as Macro
  replacement of \texttt{SubStage\stage}:
  \begin{center}
    \CurrentSubStage\ is the same as \csname SubStage\stage \endcsname .
  \end{center}
  But really they are different: Consider first the output from looping over
  \texttt{CurrentSubStage}:
  \begin{itemize}
    \foreach [count=\ii] \substage in \CurrentSubStage {
      \item Substage number \ii\ is \substage
    }
  \end{itemize}
  and then this output from looping over \texttt{SubStageOne}:
  \begin{itemize}
    \foreach [count=\ii] \substage in \SubStageOne {
      \item Substage number \ii\ is \substage
    }
  \end{itemize}
}

In the second \verb|\stage| iteration, i.e. ``Two'', I want to loop over
\verb|\SubStageTwo| as in the \verb|\SubStageOne| that creates four rather
than one item. But I do not know how to to call \verb|\Substage\stage| (This
is why I created \verb|\CurrentSubStage|). My questions:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item How can I define macro \verb|\CurrentSubStage| such that it does not
    treat the set of numbers as a single string so that the corresponding
    \verb|\substage| loop gives an iteration for each number? 
  \item Is there a possibility to do something like:\\
    \verb|\foreach [count=\ii] \substage in \SubStage\stage { ...|?
  \item I need to define an ``output'' macro at the end of each \verb|\stage|
    iteration: Something like \verb|\newcommand{\SubStageOutputOne}| in
    iteration One and \verb|\newcommand{\SubStageTwoOutput}| in iteration
    Two. (In my application, this output is a permutation of the set
    |\CurrentSubStage|. I want to ``save'' this permutation in a macro and call
    it later, at the end of the document.) In short, how can I include 
    something like \verb|\newcommand{\SubStageOutput\stage}| at the end of each
    \verb|\stage| loop? 
\end{enumerate}

[Final note: For my actual purpose, the set \verb|\Stage| contains 6 elements
and each \verb|\SubStage| set contains between 3 and 10 elements each.]

\end{document}
```