# Special characters doesn't work with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: input-encodings

I have a problem with LaTeX on my mac. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, norsk]{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Syrehydrolyse av polysakkarider og bestemmelse av reduserende ender}
\author{\bf{Jenny Nesje, Maja Knudsen og Mats Jønland}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hei

\end{document}
```

When I press 'Typeset' in TeXShop, I get this:

[image]

Can anyone help me? I thought \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} should help me with special characters as æ, ø and å?

Comment: your code works without any issue running `pdflatex` (via TexMaker) for me. Have you tried running LaTeX via command line?

Comment: It works here too. Perhaps your editor didn't actually save the file with utf-8 encoding? Anyway, if you'll require to write often in utf-8, I would suggest you to switch to xelatex.

Comment: It works on my machine as well. I think our best guess is that your editor didn't actually save the file in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: BTW: `\bf` is not a macro like `\emph{...}`, it is a switch and thus needs to be used like `{\bf foo}`, not like `\bf{foo}`. But you should probably use `\textbf{...}` anyway. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/35864,

Comment: How can I check if it's saved in UTF-8 encoding? (Thanks for the tip about \bf)

Comment: JLDiaz: If I use XeLaTeX the letter ø doesn't show up.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be using TeXShop, for which there's a very easy solution: add

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

at the top of your file and save it. Now it should compile properly.

Next, open the preferences for TeXShop and go to the “Source” tab. You probably will have a window like

[image]

(at least in the “Encoding” box): for historical reasons, TeXShop keeps MacRoman as the default text encoding.

From the  “Encoding” pull-down menu, choose “Unicode (UTF-8)”

[image]

Close the preferences and from now on, all files will be saved as UTF-8.
Having the “magic line” makes no harm, so you can keep it for greater safety.

If you have older files where `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` is used, be sure to add the magic line corresponding to MacRoman, which you can add from the “Macros>Encoding” menu.

Do this addition ***before*** changing the default encoding.