# Table using \multicolum and \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, booktabs, threeparttable

I'm working on Latex to generate the following table,

[image]

I want columns that have numbers to be right aligned and similar sized.

Here is a minimal code example to start the discussion:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\caption{Descomposici\'on est\'atica del \'{\i}ndice de Theil del ingreso per c\'apita familiar}

\begin{threeparttable}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr@{}}
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{A\~no} & \multirow{3}{*}{Theil global} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Hogares no conformados por adultos mayores} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Hogares conformados por adultos mayores} \\
\cline{3-6}\cline{7-10}
 &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Contribuci\'on} & & & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Contribuci\'on} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Efecto Intragrupal} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Efecto Intergrupal} & \\
 &  & Theil & Pob \% & Abs & Rel \% & Theil & Pob \% & Abs & Rel \% & Abs & Rel \% & Abs & Rel \% \\ \hline
\midrule
2003 & 0,448 & 0,458 & 79,5 & 0,349 & 78,1 & 0,403 & 20,5 & 0,096 & 21,3        & 0,445 & 99,4 & 0,003 & 0,7 \\
2004 & 0,421 & 0,445 & 79,5 & 0,340 & 80,8 & 0,332 & 20,5 & 0,078 & 18,6 & 0,418 & 99,4 & 0,003 & 0,7 \\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item Fuente: Elaboraci\'on propia en base a la EPH.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

From this code, I get this table:

[image]

As you can see, I cannot set a similar size for the columns that have numbers. I went over the threads that discuss `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`, but I still don't understand how to make these columns evenly distributed. What can I do to resolve this?

Thank you,

Comment: Off topic: Currently with UTF8 encoding it is not needed write "Descomposici\'on" or "A\~no". Just write "Año" and compile it with xelatex or lualatex, or with pdflatex but in this case add  `\usepackage[ut8]{inputenc}` in the preamble.

Comment: Thank you @Fran. I'll try to implement your suggestion. I'm using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` already, and compiling with TeXShop, but the Spanish characters don't appear.

Comment: Try only `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document} Año  camión \end{document}` . It  must work with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I just found out the way to use the special Spanish characters following this explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271977/148321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `\resizebox` -- as you've found out, the size of the glyphs becomes so small as to make them virtually illegible. Instead, use `tabularx` environment and permit linebreaks in the two large header cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e}   
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page size parameters suitably

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' col.

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
%\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Descomposici\'on est\'atica del \'indice de Theil del ingreso per c\'apita familiar}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{13}{C} @{}}
\toprule
A\~no & Theil global 
& \multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+8\tabcolsep\relax}C}{Hogares no conformados por adultos mayores} 
& \multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+8\tabcolsep\relax}C}{Hogares conformados por adultos mayores} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-10}
 & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Contribuci\'on} 
   & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Contribuci\'on} 
       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Intragrupal} 
       & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Intergrupal} \\
\cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(l){13-14}

 &  & Theil & Pob\,\% & Abs & Rel\,\% 
    & Theil & Pob\,\% & Abs & Rel\,\% 
    & Abs   & Rel\,\% & Abs & Rel\,\% \\ 
\midrule
2003 & 0,448 & 0,458 & 79,5 & 0,349 & 78,1 
             & 0,403 & 20,5 & 0,096 & 21,3 
             & 0,445 & 99,4 & 0,003 & 0,7 \\
2004 & 0,421 & 0,445 & 79,5 & 0,340 & 80,8 
             & 0,332 & 20,5 & 0,078 & 18,6 
             & 0,418 & 99,4 & 0,003 & 0,7 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\smallskip
\small
\begin{tablenotes}
\item{}Fuente: Elaboraci\'on propia en base a la EPH.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico! Your suggestion makes the table exactly as I need it. That's wonderful!

Comment: @eagu_999 - I was going mostly by the screenshot of what you said you wanted to replicate. You're obviously free to make changes.

Comment: I would upgrade the table in two ways. Firstly, I would align the text of the first two colums in the botton of the cell. This is something that I partially achieved by placing "Año" and "Theil" at the begining of the third row of `\multicolumn` statements, and "global" just before "Theil" in the row rigth after the second `\cmidrule`. Secondly, I would use the title "Efecto intra-grupal" and "Efecto inter-grupal" instead of only the "intra-grupal" and "inter-grupal", but I couldn't get a good solution for this.

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes when answering to your post because I'm new to this forum. But, I certainly try to practice to do better next time.