# Declaring new biblatex options

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to create my own `biblatex` style, and I want to give an option to show titles in italics or bold.

Based on other style files, I tried this:

```
\newtoggle{bftitle}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{bftitle}[true]{
    \settoggle{bftitle}{#1}}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{bftitle=true}
\iftoggle{bftitle}{
    \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    }{}
```

And this:

```
\newbool{bftitle}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{bftitle}{
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\global\booltrue{bftitle}}
    {\global\boolfalse{bftitle}}}
\ifbool{bftitle}{
    \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    }{}
```

Neither option works. Whatever I use when I call `biblatex` (`bftitle=true` or `bftitle=false`), the result is always the same (sometimes always bold, sometimes always italics).

I don't know if the problem could be `ExecuteBibliographyOptions`… I couldn't figure out how to use these commands, the documentation says very little about them.

So what am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you come up with a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? That way it is easier for us to see exactly what you are seeing. If you drop the toggle and move all the formatting commands directly into the option declaration it should work.

Comment: Please not that `\bfseries` is a switch and not a macro (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/35864) ), it is probably nicer to use `\mkbibbold` here anyway: `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the tip about `mkbibbold`. I also use `scshape` in my code, do you know if there's a macro for that? I tired googling it now but didn't find anything about it.

Comment: There is no dedicated `biblatex` wrapper for small caps, but `\scshape{foo}` is still wrong, use `\textsc{foo}` instead (or `{\scshape foo}` if you insist on `\scshape `).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a 'timing issue'. The command `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` applies some settings 'now' (to set defaults) but doesn't pick up any users choices. Those apply *after* your file has been read. As such

```
\ifbool{bftitle}{
    \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\bfseries{#1}}
    }{}
```

will always get the value of the bool you've set up in your code, not what you've passed as an option.

You need to arrange that the settings are 'dynamic' and alter each time the option(s) are called. The typical way is to put the check 'inside' the formatting

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\ifbool{bftitle}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
```

or to make the option itself do a test

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{bftitle}[true]{
    \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
     {
       \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibbold{##1}}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibbold{##1}}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibbold{##1}}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\mkbibbold{##1}}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\mkbibbold{##1}}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibbold{##1}}
     }
     {
       \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{##1}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{##1}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{##1}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{##1}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{##1}
       \DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{##1}
     }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much. I couldn't figure out that first option, but the second one, with @moewe's correction, worked like a charm! The first option could be useful in other cases, so it would be great if you could clarify it a little. How exactly should I declare the option and the bool in that case? I tried it like in my example, changing just the `DeclareFieldFormat` parts to how you mentioned, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ha! Ok, I figured out the first option too. Thanks again! :)