# How to add the copyright notice at the left of the footer on the first page and add the conference name at the center of the Header?

Tags: fancyhdr

```
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy} 
\chead[H]{2016 IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining (ASONAM)}
\lfoot{IEEE/ACM ASONAM 2016, August 18-21\\2016, San Francisco, CA,     USA\\
978-1-5090-2846-7/16/\$~\copyright~2016 IEEE}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

How to add the copyright notice at the left of the footer on the first page and add the conference name at the center of the Header in IEEE two columns format? What's wrong with my method? I want to add the footer only at the first page and add the header at every page, but I always failed. If I do it according to traditional method, the footer appears in every page!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think we would need an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) here, with some more information about your expected output. As it stands now, your questions is unclear.

Comment: the template I use is IEEE two column format. I want to add the footer only at the first page, but I always failed.

Comment: How about posting a Minimum Working Example (MWE) which at least includes `\documentclass` and `\begin` environments? Also, you can highlight other users by placing `@` in front of their user name AND at the beginning of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `fancyhdr` to set up footer and headers of your pages, you can create pagestyles that can easily be switched between in your documents. I have here created two page styles. You can name them whatever you like, in this example, I have used "FirstPage", and "AllPages".

Set up a pagestyle like this:

`\fancypagestyle{pageStyleName}{\chead{whatever}…other commands}`

These are created in the preamble, and to set the default one, use `\pagestyle{AllPages}`, in the preamble. Now every page uses this style. To change the style, you can at any time in your document change it for a single page using `\thispagestyle{FirstPage}`, or set it for all the following pages with the command`\pagestyle{pageStyleName}`.

If you are using two-sided printing, you probably want different headers and footers on odd and even pages. This can be done using commands like `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}`, which will set the page number on the outer part of the footer. (L)eft side (E)ven page, (R)ight side (O)dd page.

All this is explained in the documentation, which I encourage you to skim through.

Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc fancyhdr`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr

It might sound tedious to look up the documentation for various small problems/features, but the package documentations tend to be well-written and easy to browse. Also, it will at the same time help you to understand how LaTeX works.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\title{Some title}
\author{John Doe}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{AllPages}{
\chead{2016 IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining (ASONAM)}
}
\fancypagestyle{FirstPage}{
\chead{2016 IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining (ASONAM)}
\lfoot{IEEE/ACM ASONAM 2016, August 18-21\\2016, San Francisco, CA,     USA\\
978-1-5090-2846-7/16/\$~\copyright~2016 IEEE}
}

\chead{2016 IEEE/ACM International Conference on Advances in Social Networks Analysis and Mining (ASONAM)}

\pagestyle{AllPages} % This sets the page style for every pages
\usepackage{lipsum} %Example text
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{FirstPage} % This sets the page style for only this page

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: No..I want to add the footer only at the first page and add the header at every page, but I always failed. If I do it according to your method, the footer appears in every page!

Comment: @user38851 see updated answer

Comment: It works!, thanks very much! But I has one more question. If I want adjust the size of header or footer, how can I modify my code?

Comment: @user38851 great that it worked. Could you please add your first comment here to your question, so that it is clear what you intended? I'll explain my answer a bit better

Comment: Yes, I will. Thanks for your help. The conference program asks me to add the "bold" font. I want to know whether it means "\textbf{}" or "\bf{}"

Comment: don't use `\bf`. either use `{\bfseries text}`, or `\textbf{text}` See [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text?lq=1)

Comment: Use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` to disable numbering on footer

Comment: @Shnkc I don't quite follow on how this is relevant to the neither the question or my answer. Are you answering a deleted comment?

Comment: @Runar Trollet AFAIK for asonam, pages of the paper shouldn't be numbered. This is how it is in conference template. But the answer above puts page number on footer. I have written for disabling numbering for this reason.

Comment: @Shnkc well, that would be specific to a special document, and not really related to the question at hand. One could use `\chead{}` to remove pagenumbers.