# Why is the \bf command applied to more than I asked?

Tags: math-mode, bm

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$$x(t), \bf{x}(t), \bf{x(t)}$$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Question:

Why are the second and third `x(t)` typeset the same? In the second  expression, it was asked to apply `\bf` to only `x`.

**EDIT:**

I had not payed attention to it when asking the question, but I would like to have a bold and italic `x`.

Comment: Because `\bf` is a declaration that applies to everything until the end of the current group. Use `\mathbf{x}(t)` instead. Nowadays (=the last thirty years) one doesn't use `\bf` anymore.

Comment: You probably intended to write `\bm` instead of `\bf`.

Comment: Better to avoid `$$...$$`. Use `\[...\]` instead. [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/110998)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\bm` instead of `\bf`. And [`\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/110998).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\[x(t), \bm{x}(t), \bm{x(t)}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `\mathbf{x}` rather than `\bm{x}`

Comment: @egreg It depends on what you mean by "want". Loading the `bm` package and adding the `bm` tag indicates that the OP wants to use the `bm` package, so it seems that `\bf` is just `\bm` with a typo. If by "want" you mean "should want" then I have no opinion. I'm neither able to read the OP's subconscious mind, nor am I aware of typographic conventions that dictate `\mathbf` instead of `\bm`.

Comment: @egreg No, I wanted `\bm{x}` (x italic), but it is true that I had not mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @Karlo Well, you mentioned it in the question. You can hardly be more explicit than`\usepackage{bm}` and adding the tag `bm`.

Comment: @egreg Ah yes, it was a typo apparently.

Answer (score 12):

Because `\bf` is a (deprecated) *switch* that is turned *on*. It doesn't take an argument in the form `\bf{x}`, but should rather be used `{\bfseries x}` (instead of `{\bf x}`. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and 
[Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Instead, use `\boldsymbol` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) or `\mathbf`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ x(t), \boldsymbol{x}(t), \mathbf{x}(t), \boldsymbol{x(t)}, \mathbf{x(t)} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note the use of `\[`...`\]` (as opposed to `$$`...`$$`). See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: The documentation of `amsbsy` (automatically loaded by `amsmath`) explicitly tells to prefer `\bm` from the `bm` package.

Comment: I'm not sure it's right to call the switches like `\bf` and `\it` deprecated: they may be deprecated in LaTeX (not fitting with its philosophy of logical structure), but AFAIK they are still the way to go in plain TeX, and one could argue there is something pleasing about transparently getting exactly the font you asked for: not getting bold italics because of accidental nesting or whatever.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR they're are not deprecated in Plain and ConTeXt but *they are* in LaTeX. Since the question clearly is about a LaTeX document it would be rather misleading (IMHO) not to call them deprecated under these circumstances.