# Reference didnt appear in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{apacite}
\newcommand{\mathnrleg}{\textnormal{\textnrleg}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item The log-likelihood function for without any imputation method is 
\[
 l(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \delta_{E_i}\log[f(t_i)]+\delta_{R_i}\log [S(t_{R_i})]+\delta_{I_i}\log[S(t_{L_i})-S(t_{R_i})]
\]
\item The log-likelihood function for midpoint imputation method is 
\[
 l(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \delta_{E_i}\log[f(t_i)]+\delta_{R_i}\log [S(t_{R_i})]+\delta_{I_i}\log[f(\tilde t_i)]
\]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\bf References}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why my references wont appear in the slide? i have already run bibtex.
bib:

```
@article{dwivedi2016survival,
  title={Survival analysis: A brief note},
  author={Dwivedi, Nidhi and Sachdeva, Sandeep and others},
  journal={Journal of Current Research in Scientific Medicine},
  volume={2},
  number={2},
  pages={73},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Medknow Publications}
}
@article{el2013generalized,
  title={The generalized Gompertz distribution},
  author={El-Gohary, Alshamrani and Alshamrani, Ahmad and Al-Otaibi, Adel Naif},
  journal={Applied Mathematical Modelling},
  volume={37},
  number={1},
  pages={13--24},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{weymouth1931latitude,
  title={Latitude and relative growth in the razor clam, Siliqua patula},
  author={Weymouth, FW and McMillin, HC and Rich, Willis H},
  journal={Journal of Experimental Biology},
  volume={8},
  number={3},
  pages={228--249},
  year={1931},
  publisher={The Company of Biologists Ltd}
}
@book{weymouth1931age,
  title={The age and growth of the Pacific cockle (Cardium corbis, Martyn)},
  author={Weymouth, Frank Walter and Thompson, Seton Hayes},
  number={1101},
  year={1931},
  publisher={US Government Printing Office}
}
@article{tjorve2017use,
  title={The use of Gompertz models in growth analyses, and new Gompertz-model approach: An addition to the Unified-Richards family},
  author={Tj{\o}rve, Kathleen MC and Tj{\o}rve, Even},
  journal={PloS one},
  volume={12},
  number={6},
  pages={e0178691},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Public Library of Science}
}
@article{gompertz1825nature,
  title={On the nature of the function expressive of the law of human mortality, and on a new mode of determining the value of life contingencies},
  author={Gompertz, Benjamin},
  journal={Philosophical transactions of the Royal Society of London},
  volume={115},
  pages={513--583},
  year={1825},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
@article{davidson1928growth,
  title={Growth and senescence in purebred Jersey cows},
  author={Davidson, Frederick Alexander},
  journal={Bulletin (University of Illinois (Urbana-Champaign campus). Agricultural Experiment Station); no. 302},
  year={1928},
  publisher={Urbana, Ill.: University of Illinois Agricultural Experiment Station,}
}
@article{laird1964dynamics,
  title={Dynamics of tumour growth},
  author={Laird, Anna Kane},
  journal={British journal of cancer},
  volume={18},
  number={3},
  pages={490},
  year={1964},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
@article{gibson1987effect,
  title={The effect of sodium chloride and temperature on the rate and extent of growth of Clostridium botulinum type A in pasteurized pork slurry},
  author={Gibson, Angela M and Bratchell, N and Roberts, TA},
  journal={Journal of Applied microbiology},
  volume={62},
  number={6},
  pages={479--490},
  year={1987},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{riffenburgh2001survival,
  title={Survival patterns of cancer patients},
  author={Riffenburgh, RH and Johnstone, PAS},
  journal={Cancer},
  volume={91},
  number={12},
  pages={2469--2475},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{gordon1990maximum,
  title={Maximum likelihood estimation for mixtures of two Gompertz distributions when censoring occurs},
  author={Gordon, NH},
  journal={Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation},
  volume={19},
  number={2},
  pages={733--747},
  year={1990},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@article{lenart2012gompertz,
  title={The Gompertz distribution and Maximum Likelihood Estimation of its parameters-a revision},
  author={Lenart, Adam and others},
  journal={MPDIR Work Pap},
  volume={49},
  pages={0--19},
  year={2012}
}
@article{chen1997parameter,
  title={Parameter estimation of the Gompertz population},
  author={Chen, Zhenmin},
  journal={Biometrical Journal},
  volume={39},
  number={1},
  pages={117--124},
  year={1997},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{arasan2008alternative,
  title={Alternative interval estimation for parameters of bivariate exponential model with time varying covariate},
  author={Arasan, Jayanthi and Lunn, Mary},
  journal={Computational Statistics},
  volume={23},
  number={4},
  pages={605--622},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{arasan2009interval,
  title={Interval estimation for parameters of a bivariate time varying covariate model},
  author={Arasan, Jayanthi},
  journal={Pertanika Journal of Science and Technology},
  volume={17},
  number={2},
  pages={313--323},
  year={2009}
}
@article{arasan2009survival,
  title={Survival model of a parallel system with dependent failures and time varying covariates},
  author={Arasan, Jayanthi and Lunn, Mary},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference},
  volume={139},
  number={3},
  pages={944--951},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{efron1985bootstrap,
  title={Bootstrap confidence intervals for a class of parametric problems},
  author={Efron, Bradley},
  journal={Biometrika},
  volume={72},
  number={1},
  pages={45--58},
  year={1985},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@article{kiani2013gompertz,
  title={Gompertz model with time-dependent covariate in the presence of interval-, right-and left-censored data},
  author={Kiani, Kaveh and Arasan, Jayanthi},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation},
  volume={83},
  number={8},
  pages={1472--1490},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@inproceedings{dunnigan2008confidence,
  title={Confidence interval calculation for binomial proportions},
  author={Dunnigan, Keith},
  booktitle={Midwest SAS Users Group Conference, Indianapolis, Ind},
  year={2008}
}
@book{cox1979theoretical,
  title={Theoretical statistics},
  author={Cox, David Roxbee and Hinkley, David Victor},
  year={1979},
  publisher={CRC Press}
}
@misc{StatNews5,
 author= "{Cornell University Cornell Statistical Consulting Unit}",
  title = {What is Maximum Likelihood?},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.cscu.cornell.edu/news/statnews/stnews50.pdf}},
  note = {Online; Accessed 8 December 2017},
  year = {2002},
} 
@book{lee2003statistical,
  title={Statistical methods for survival data analysis},
  author={Lee, Elisa T and Wang, John},
  volume={476},
  year={2003},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
@article{clark2003survival,
  title={Survival analysis part I: basic concepts and first analyses},
  author={Clark, TG and Bradburn, MJ and Love, SB and Altman, DG},
  journal={British journal of cancer},
  volume={89},
  number={2},
  pages={232},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
@book{miller2010inverse,
  title={Inverse Transform Sampling},
  author={Miller, F.P. and Vandome, A.F. and John, M.B.},
  isbn={9786131753268},
  year={2010},
  publisher={VDM Publishing}
}
@book{wicklin2013simulating,
  title={Simulating data with SAS},
  author={Wicklin, Rick},
  year={2013},
  publisher={SAS Institute}
}
@book{frieden2010exploratory,
  title={Exploratory data analysis using Fisher information},
  author={Frieden, Roy and Gatenby, Robert A},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
@book{everitt2005encyclopedia,
  title={Encyclopedia of statistics in behavioral science.},
  author={Everitt, Brian S and Howell, David C},
  year={2005},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons Ltd}
}
@article{arasan2014double,
  title={Double bootstrap confidence interval estimates with censored and truncated data},
  author={Arasan, Jayanthi and Adam, Mohd B},
  journal={Journal of Modern Applied Statistical Methods},
  volume={13},
  number={2},
  pages={22},
  year={2014}
}
@article{kiani2012interval,
  title={Interval estimations for parameters of Gompertz model with time-dependent covariate and right censored data},
  author={Kiani, Kaveh and Arasan, Jayanthi and Midi, Habshah},
  journal={Sains Malaysiana},
  volume={41},
  number={4},
  pages={471--480},
  year={2012}
}
@book{efron1982jackknife,
  title={The jackknife, the bootstrap and other resampling plans},
  author={Efron, Bradley},
  year={1982},
  publisher={SIAM}
}
@book{efron1994introduction,
  title={An introduction to the bootstrap},
  author={Efron, Bradley and Tibshirani, Robert J},
  year={1994},
  publisher={CRC press}
}
@inproceedings{fang2015jackknife,
  title={Jackknife and bootstrap inferential procedures for censored survival data},
  author={Fang, Loh Yue and Arasan, Jayanthi and Midi, Habshah and Bakar, Mohd Rizam Abu},
  booktitle={AIP Conference Proceedings},
  volume={1682},
  number={1},
  pages={050021},
  year={2015},
  organization={AIP Publishing}
}
@article{hosmer1999applied,
  title={Applied survival analysis: regression modelling of time to event data (1999)},
  author={Hosmer Jr, David W and Lemeshow, Stanley},
  journal={Eur Orthodontic Soc},
  pages={561--2},
  year={1999}
}
@book{lawless2011statistical,
  title={Statistical models and methods for lifetime data},
  author={Lawless, Jerald F},
  volume={362},
  year={2011},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
@book{collett2015modelling,
  title={Modelling survival data in medical research},
  author={Collett, David},
  year={2015},
  publisher={CRC press}
}
@inproceedings{smith2001survival,
  title={Survival analysis and the application of Cox's proportional hazards modeling using SAS},
  author={Smith, Tyler and Smith, Besa},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the twenty-sixth annual SAS user's group international conference},
  pages={244--246},
  year={2001},
  organization={SAS Institute Inc Cary (NC)}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings/errors when you run bibtex? Did you compile with latex before and after you run bibtex? Is `slide.bib` in the same folder?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: i didnt get any warning when run bibtex. yes i compile before and after i run bibtex. and yes it's in the same folder.

Comment: @yap: Unrelated, but please don't use `\bf` for bold text. Instead use `\textbf` or `\bfseries` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144)

Comment: Even better: don't manually disturb with font commands, use `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}` instead.

Comment: @yap Can you show us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that also includes the necessary .bib entries to reproduce your problem? Can you show us the log file of your MWE?

Comment: i have already added the bib entries but where to get the log file?

Comment: and i realised the problem is caused by this line :  l(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \delta_{E_i}\log[f(t_i)]+\delta_{R_i}\log [S(t_{R_i})]+\delta_{I_i}\log[S(t_{L_i})-S(t_{R_i})]. after i delete this line, references appear. i really dont know whats wrong.....

Comment: With the sequence `pdflatex` - `bibtex` - `pdflatex` - `pdflatex` I get the reference, without changing anything of your code. The `.log` file is placed in the same folder as your `.tex` file (unless you're using `output-directory`).

Comment: thanks! i got it with this sequence. previously i was using pdflatex+makeIndex+Bibtex > bibtex > pdflatex+makeIndex+Bibtex

Comment: Off-topic: Be sure to encase surnames (Gompertz, Cox, Fisher, Richards), geographic references (Pacific) and acronyms (SAS, AIP) in `title` and `booktitle` fields in curly braces, to prevent them from being rendered in lowercase.

Comment: @yap Hi, do you have the template of statistical planning and inference journal?