# Bold font of chord in latex pkg. guitar

Tags: fonts

I use the [guitar package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/guitar).

The documentation says I can redefine `\guitarPreAccord` command to change font size, but I want guitar chords to be printed in bold. I tried this and it didn't work:

```
\renewcommand\guitarPreAccord{\footnotesize\strut\textbf}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `\bfseries` in this case. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text) for an explainer.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{guitar}
    \renewcommand\guitarPreAccord{\footnotesize\strut\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{guitar}
[Cm]This [Bb]is a [G#]very [Gm]simple song.
\end{guitar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I also change the color of the chords?
I tried some things without any luck.....