# Table is bigger than page; words do not fit

Tags: tables, width, tabu

I have been struggling with making tables for a while now.

I've got a pretty nice layout now, however the table does not fit the page. I looked in tabu documentation (it says `\begin{tabu} to <dimension> ....`), but it still does not work.

The words in the table do not stop at the end of the line to fit the table, but continue outside of the page.

Can anybody help?

code:

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\caption{Overzicht belangrijkste wetgeving over honing}
\label{tab:example}
\centering
\taburulecolor{ocre}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {| l || l |}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!5}
\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}Eigenschap & \small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}Wettelijke vereisten \\
\hline    
\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}Algemeen &  \\
Bijenras & Apis mellifera \\
Geur & Normaal, afgeleid van de plant van oorsprong\\
Smaak & Normaal, afgeleid van de plant van oorsprong \\
Kleur & Bijna kleurloos tot donkerbruin \\
Consistentie & Vloeibaar, dikvloeibaar, of – gedeeltelijk of geheel – gekristalliseerd \\
Gisting & Niet toegestaan \\
Geleidbaarheid & Bloemenhoning: max. 0,8 mS/cm \\
& Honingdauwhoning: min. 0,8 mS/cm \\
Hoge druk filtratie  & Toegestaan voor bloemenhoning (met uitzondering van uniflorale honingsoorten), mits vermeld op etiket. \\
(diameter 50 micrometer) \\
Verder: & zoveel mogelijk vrij van organische of anorganische vreemde  bestanddelen;\\
& niet op zodanige wijze verwarmd dat de natuurlijke enzymen zijn vernietigd  of in aanzienlijke mate onwerkzaam zijn gemaakt;\\
& de zuurtegraad is niet kunstmatig gewijzigd; \\
& geen pollen noch enig ander bestanddeel dat specifiek is voor honing is      onttrokken, tenzij dit bij het verwijderen van vreemde anorganische of      organische stoffen onvermijdelijk is \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: that we can help you, we need complete but small document with your table beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: For an explaation why not to use `\bf`, you can have a look here: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144) and here [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/134144)

Answer (score 3):

mostly off-topic, focused to more correct use of `tabu` tables ...

use of the package `tabu` is not recommended. it is not maintained, consequently it not consider recent changes in packages which is based. however, in your case this is not yet a problem, so see, if the following mwe can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\newcommand\RC[1]{\small\bfseries\sffamily\textcolor{brown!50!yellow}{#1}}
    \centering
    \tabulinestyle{1pt brown!50!yellow}
    \tabulinesep=3pt

\caption{Overzicht belangrijkste wetgeving over honing}
\label{tab:example}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth  { l X }
    \tabucline-
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
\RC{Eigenschap} & \RC{Wettelijke vereisten}                     \\
    \tabucline-
\RC{Algemeen}   &                                               \\
Bijenras        & Apis mellifera                                \\
Geur            & Normaal, afgeleid van de plant van oorsprong  \\
Smaak           & Normaal, afgeleid van de plant van oorsprong  \\
Kleur           & Bijna kleurloos tot donkerbruin               \\
Consistentie    & Vloeibaar, dikvloeibaar, of – gedeeltelijk of geheel – gekristalliseerd \\
Gisting         & Niet toegestaan                               \\
Geleidbaarheid  & Bloemenhoning: max. \SI{0,8}{mS/cm}           \\
                & Honingdauwhoning: min. \SI{0,8}{mS/cm}        \\
Hoge druk filtratie
                & Toegestaan voor bloemenhoning (met uitzondering van uniflorale honingsoorten), mits vermeld op etiket. (diameter \SI{50}{\micro\meter})        \\
Verder:         & zoveel mogelijk vrij van organische of anorganische vreemde  bestanddelen;\\
                & niet op zodanige wijze verwarmd dat de natuurlijke enzymen zijn vernietigd  of in aanzienlijke mate onwerkzaam zijn gemaakt;                   \\
                & de zuurtegraad is niet kunstmatig gewijzigd;  \\
                & geen pollen noch enig ander bestanddeel dat specifiek is voor honing is onttrokken, tenzij dit bij het verwijderen van vreemde anorganische of organische stoffen onvermijdelijk is \\
    \tabucline-
\end{tabu}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

since you not provide mwe (minimal working example) from which we can get information of your page layout and color definiton, i consider standard `article` as document class and try mimic `ocre` color (i suppose that this is mix of brown and yellow color). this you can simple change to your wish.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package might be what you're looking for. It provides an additional column type `X` which automatically wraps lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% Include tabularx package, which allows usage of the tabularx environment and the 'X' column type
\usepackage{tabularx}
% Fix spacing of captions above table
\usepackage{caption}

% Define a custom command for colored, small, bold text (borrowed from Zarko's answer)
\newcommand\RC[1]{\small\bfseries\sffamily\textcolor{brown!50!yellow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\arrayrulecolor{brown!50!yellow}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\caption{Overzicht belangrijkste wetgeving over honing}
\label{tab:example}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l || X |}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black!5}
    \RC{Eigenschap}     & \RC{Wettelijke vereisten} \\
    \hline    
    \RC{Algemeen}       & \\
    Bijenras            & Apis mellifera \\
    Geur                & Normaal, afgeleid van de plant van oorsprong\\
    Smaak               & Normaal, afgeleid van de plant van oorsprong \\
    Kleur               & Bijna kleurloos tot donkerbruin \\
    Consistentie        & Vloeibaar, dikvloeibaar, of – gedeeltelijk of geheel – gekristalliseerd \\
    Gisting             & Niet toegestaan \\
    Geleidbaarheid      & Bloemenhoning: max. 0,8 mS/cm \\
                        & Honingdauwhoning: min. 0,8 mS/cm \\
    Hoge druk filtratie & Toegestaan voor bloemenhoning (met uitzondering van uniflorale honingsoorten), mits vermeld op etiket. \\
    (diameter 50 micrometer) \\
    Verder:             & zoveel mogelijk vrij van organische of anorganische vreemde  bestanddelen;\\
                        & niet op zodanige wijze verwarmd dat de natuurlijke enzymen zijn vernietigd  of in aanzienlijke mate onwerkzaam zijn gemaakt;\\
                        & de zuurtegraad is niet kunstmatig gewijzigd; \\
                        & geen pollen noch enig ander bestanddeel dat specifiek is voor honing is onttrokken, tenzij dit bij het verwijderen van vreemde anorganische of organische stoffen onvermijdelijk is \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered LaTeX]

Comment: Your code does not compile, as it misses the `table` option to `xcolor` (and the definition of the color 'ocre').

Comment: @leandriis It produced a PDF for me. Good points though! Fixed the issues and used the ocre definition from Zarko's answer.

Comment: sine you solution is based on `tabularx` you should remove all what is from `tabu`. for collumn headers see solution in my answer, discrepancy can be removed with use `\textcolor{<coloe>}{text}` ...

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the feedback! I've adapted the answer.

Comment: The     [tabularx] environment worked out fine. Thank you so much. The next problem is how to get the table to split over pages. I read to remove the 'table' environment, however that did not work out for me.

Comment: @JosienBoetje Glad we could help. `tabularx` does not help with splitting a table over multiple pages. Check out the [`ltablex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) package which combines the `tabularx` (auto-sized columns) and `longtable` (multi-page ta­bles) packages. Maybe open another question for help with this? If this question is answered, you could accept one of the answers.