# Background color of the title of a theorem, including its numbering

Tags: color, theorems

I am starting with a classical theorem environment from `amsthm`, it has the numbering I want. What I would like is to color the background of the name of the theorem. I have tried to do a color box in the definition itself, but I only get to color the name, unfortunately without the numbering. Basically, my question is: how to get the numbering to be colored as well?

I am aware of the package `thmtools` but I am only trying to color the background of the name and numbering, not the whole theorem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{1}{RGB}{255,200,255}
\newtheorem{prop1}{\colorbox{1}{Proposition}}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop1}
For any information provision policy $A$,
\[
\rho^*_A = 1.
\]
\end{prop1}

\end{document}
```

[image: Solely <code>Proposition' is colored, whereas I would like the numbering</code>1.' to be colored as well.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own theorem style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{1}{RGB}{255,200,255}
\newtheoremstyle{colth}% 
{}{}% 
{\itshape}{}% 
{}{}% 
{ }% 
{\colorbox{1}{\textbf{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}}\thmnote{ (#3)}.}}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{colth}
\newtheorem{prop1}[prop]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
An ordinary Proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{prop1}
For any information provision policy $A$,
\[
\rho^*_A = 1.
\]
\end{prop1}

\begin{prop}[With a note]
For any information provision policy $A$,
\[
\rho^*_A = 1.
\]
\end{prop}

\begin{prop1}[With a note]
For any information provision policy $A$,
\[
\rho^*_A = 1.
\]
\end{prop1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, it works like a charm. I would just add that I used \bf to make the text bold-faced, to be more coherent with the other theorem style.

Comment: @OlivierMassicot `\bf` is deprecated, use `\bfseries` instead, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text and see my edit.

Comment: I see, thank you! However I noticed that the numbering counts the number of `prop1` theorems, and obviously not the number of propositions. Is there a way where I can have a `prop1` and `prop2` defined, such that the numbering is the sum of the numberings, i.e. so that it goes Proposition 1., Proposition 2., etc. irrespective of the colors?

Or is there a way to pass the color as an argument, something like `\begin{colorprop}[red] ... \end{colorprop}`?

Comment: Yes, I think I should have framed my initial question differently. I am basically using a color code to refer to propositions in a visual way. I need a color only once, thus I need many propositions with a different style each. No worry, thank you!

Comment: @OlivierMassicot See if my renewed answer fits your needs.

Comment: Yes it does! I ticked the green check mark.

Comment: @OlivierMassicot Thank you for accepting my answer.