# table title setting

Tags: tables, captions

I use `\begin{longtable}` to  edit a table to change page, and the title is as follows:

[image]

But I need to fit the template whose form is :

[image]

So how should I modify it?

My partial code:

```latex
\documentclass[review,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamart171218}


\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{braket,amsfonts}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
%% Used for papers with subtables created with the subfig package
\captionsetup[subtable]{position=bottom}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

%% For referencing line numbers
\Crefname{ALC@unique}{Line}{Lines}

%% For creating math operators
\usepackage{amsopn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Range}{Range}

%% ------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Macros for in-document examples. These are not meant to reused for
%% SIAM journal papers.
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{{\scshape Bib}\TeX\xspace}
\newcounter{example}
\colorlet{texcscolor}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{texemcolor}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{texpreamble}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{codebackground}{black!25!white!25}

\newcommand\bs{\symbol{'134}} % print backslash in typewriter OT1/T1
\newcommand{\preamble}[2][\small]{\textcolor{texpreamble}{#1\texttt{#2 \emph{\% <- Preamble}}}}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{>{[\;}*{#1}{R@{\;\;}}R<{\;]}}
\makeatletter\def\@captype{table}\makeatother
\captionsetup{position=top}
{\centering
\footnotesize
% \begin{center}
 \begin{longtable}{|c|c|cccc|}
 \caption{Comparison on artificial datasets}\label{tab:1}\\
 \hline
  (m,n) & p & method & ER & k & time\\
  \hline
  \multirow{20}{*}{(300,400)}
        & 0\% & \begin{tabular}{c}
         1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5\\ 6\\
           \end{tabular}
        & \begin{tabular}{c}
            \bf{1.02e-9}\\1.37e-5\\1.38e-6\\5.79e-5\\8.11e-8\\2.54e-6\\
           \end{tabular}
  \\
\hline
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)  that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but could you please also add the documentclass and the relevant packages that you use. Apart from that, your code misses a `\\ ` after the caption.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but regarding your use of `\bf`: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144) Could you please also add the reason for the nested tabular environments?

Comment: from `\documentclass` follows that article is intended to be published in some *siam* journal, so i would use caption style as they define in their document class.

Comment: @Zarko,  I hope so. But in their document class, I can't  achieve change page to set my table. When I use  \longtable , the format of  my caption will change.

Comment: complerely off topic i can not find where you use bs in your mwe. so it could be left out? and does not \texttt{\textbackslash} do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to modify the caption layout with `caption` package.

But, as Zarko said, if you have to submit your article to a journal, are you sure they agree with these changes?

Off-topic: you loaded `array` twice, and I don't say anything about your table formatting because it's not the topic of the question, but it could be improved.

```
\documentclass[review,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamart171218}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{braket,amsfonts}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
%% Used for papers with subtables created with the subfig package
\captionsetup[subtable]{position=bottom}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{>{[\;}*{#1}{R@{\;\;}}R<{\;]}}
\makeatletter\def\@captype{table}\makeatother
\captionsetup{position=top}

%% For referencing line numbers
\Crefname{ALC@unique}{Line}{Lines}

%% For creating math operators
\usepackage{amsopn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Range}{Range}

%% ------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Macros for in-document examples. These are not meant to reused for
%% SIAM journal papers.
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{{\scshape Bib}\TeX\xspace}
\newcounter{example}
\colorlet{texcscolor}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{texemcolor}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{texpreamble}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{codebackground}{black!25!white!25}

\newcommand\bs{\symbol{'134}} % print backslash in typewriter OT1/T1
\newcommand{\preamble}[2][\small]{\textcolor{texpreamble}{#1\texttt{#2 \emph{\% <- Preamble}}}}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=sc,textfont=it,labelsep = newline}
\begin{document}

{\footnotesize
 \begin{longtable}{|c|c|cccc|}
 \caption{Comparison on artificial datasets}\label{tab:1}\\
 \hline
  (m,n) & p & method & ER & k & time\\
  \hline
  \multirow{6}{*}{(300,400)}
        & 0\% & 
         1 & \bf{1.02e-9}&&\\ 
         &&2 & 1.37e-5 &&\\ 
         &&3 & 1.38e-6 &&\\ 
         &&4 & 5.79e-5 &&\\ 
         &&5 & 8.11e-8 &&\\ 
         &&6 & 2.54e-6 &&\\
\hline
\end{longtable}}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    ordinary     & table \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.   Because my table is very long.  There is no way to implement table paging with the provided table template,  so  i use the longtable package. To be honest,  I'm not sure if this is appropriate.

Comment: @wendy You're welcome! I think it's better if you ask the journal.

Comment: OK, i will.  Thank you a lot~