# Escaping the "^" character causes formatting error

Tags: fonts, formatting, shell-escape

Escaping "^" after `\tt` is causing formatting error in the following code. All words after `\^{}` is being affected by `\tt`.

Code:

```
\item Use the {\tt linspace} command to create a vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$ containing 100 equally spaced points between 0 and 10 (inclusive). Use this vector to create the Vandermonde matrix $\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times 4}$ with rows $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_i & x_i^2 & x_i^3 \end{bmatrix}$ for $i = 1,\dots,100$. (Hint: While using {\tt x\^{}n} will result in an error, using {\tt x.\^{}n} will return a vector where each element is raised to the $n$th power.) Save the matrix $\mathbf{D}$ as {\tt A4.dat}.
```

Current output:

> [image]

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, now you should not use `\tt` at all. In this case, I think `\verb` fits best

Comment: However, your code works fine for me

Comment: Independent of your question, you might be interested in this package: [`matlab-prettifier`](https://ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works file for me. However,

1. [you should not use the deprecated `\tt`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/156344). Such commands are some of the most deprecated commands in LaTeX.
2. `\verb` is for that purpose. You can use something as simple as `\verb|a^b|` to get `a^b` instead of `\texttt{a\^{}b}`; or `\verb|\cmd|` to get `\cmd` instead of `\texttt{\textbackslash{}cmd}`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Use the \verb|linspace| command to create a vector $\mathbf{x} 
\in \mathbb{R}^{100}$ containing 100 equally spaced points between 0 
and 10 (inclusive). Use this vector to create the Vandermonde matrix
$\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{100 \times 4}$ with rows $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_i & x_i^2 & x_i^3 \end{bmatrix}$ for $i = 1,\dots,100$. (Hint: 
While using \verb|x^n| will result in an error, using \verb|x.^n| will
return a vector where each element is raised to the $n$-th power.) 
Save the matrix $\mathbf{D}$ as \verb|A4.dat|.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]