# How I can introduce two columns with images and explications (no captions)?

Tags: graphics, columns

This is mi idea:

[image]

Before text, then you get 2 columns with titles, pictures and descriptions.

Thanks in advance!

Mi try:

```
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\raggedright
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk{\centering {\bf Algebra}}
\colchunk{\centering {\bf Geometry}}
\colplacechunks
\colchunk{\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Picture1}
\end{figure}}
\colchunk{\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Picture2}
\end{figure}}
\colplacechunks
\colchunk{\begin{itemize}\item The algebraic properties...\end{itemize}}
\colchunk{\begin{itemize}\item The geometric properties...\end{itemize}}
\end{parcolumns}
```

Comment: You could use 2 minipages or a tabular.

Comment: Yes, but with minipages doesn´t fit well (centered) the pictures, I don´t know why. And I´m using \begin{center}

Comment: @user198495 ... Please add what you just described here as a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @user198495: Without seeing how you use the minipages, it is impossible to tell you why you don't get the desired alignment. Therefore please add a minimal working example including the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages.

Comment: Regarding your use of `\bf`: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144)

Comment: I admitt any other (simple) model that you provide me and I´ll modified it to my context. Thanks for the \bf affair, but is not my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\medskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering \textbf{Algebra}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\begin{itemize}
  \item The algebraic properties
  \item another item
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering \textbf{Geometry}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\begin{itemize}
  \item The algebraic properties
  \item another item
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\medskip

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is use `multicol`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-7]

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section*{\centering GEOMETRY}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\subsection*{Description \#1}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\vfill\null\columnbreak

\section*{\centering ALGEBRA}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\subsection*{Description \#2}
\lipsum[3][1-8]

\vfill\null
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[4][1-7]

\end{document}
```