# How to make a list in table cell to show multiple items in a better way?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, formatting, booktabs

I am trying to show multiple-choice questions in a table along with a description & percent. Here is my attempt:

```
\begin{table*}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\toprule
 {\bf Question Type} & {\bf Percent.} & {\bf Example} \\
\midrule

Type 1  &  0.47 &\makecell{Which is not a side effect of the progestogen-only pill (POP)? \\\hfill \textbf{a)} \colorbox{mygreen}{Ovarian cysts}
   \textbf{b)} Venous thromboembolism \\
   \textbf{c}) Increased risk of diabetes mellitus
    \textbf{d)} Ectopic pregnancy}
 \\
 \hline
Type 1  &  0.47 &\makecell{Which is not a side effect of the progestogen-only pill (POP)? \\\hfill \textbf{a)} \colorbox{mygreen}{Ovarian cysts}
   \textbf{b)} Venous thromboembolism \\
   \textbf{c}) Increased risk of diabetes mellitus
    \textbf{d)} Ectopic pregnancy}
 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{tab:subject_wise}
\vspace{-2ex}
\end{table*}
```

But it's not looking good :

[image]

Is there a better way to do this? I have to show two multiple-choice questions per question type.

**Edit:**

The accepted answer's code is working well, but I am getting this error:

[image]

[image]

How to resize the table to fit it in one page?

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages and the definition of your color (or use a different, predefined color, such as `gray` instead.) (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but do not use `\bf`. Replace it with `\bfseries Example` or `\textbf{Example}`. (See also: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144))

Comment: What does "better way"  refer to? Do you want to know if there is a more efficient way to write the required code by user defined commands or are you interested in a different, probably more visually preasing output? If it's the latter, what exactly do you want to change?

Comment: @leandriis Yes, the current output is not clear and it's a mix-up, I need a clean way to show this information in the table.

Comment: What about one of the following two examples? https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3CFE.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi9Mo.png

Comment: @leandriis Second image looks clean and better. i.stack.imgur.com/Yi9Mo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\alph*),
                  font=\bfseries,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\newcommand{\correctitem}{\item[\stepcounter{tabenumi}\colorbox{mygreen}{\thetabenumi}]}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Fine-grained evaluation per medical subject in Test and Dev set}
\label{tab:subject_wise}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccX}
\toprule
 \thead{Question\\ Type} & \thead{Percent.} & \thead{Example} \\
\midrule
Type 1  &  0.47 & Which is not a side effect of the progestogen-only pill (POP)?  \\
        &       & \begin{tabenum}
                  \correctitem Ovarian cysts
                  \item  Venous thromboembolism
                  \item  Increased risk of diabetes mellitus 
                  \item  Ectopic pregnancy
                  \end{tabenum}
 \\
\midrule
Type 1  &  0.47 & Which is not a side effect of the progestogen-only pill (POP)? Ths question is a lot longer, this question is a lot longer \\
        &       & \begin{tabenum}
                  \correctitem Ovarian cysts
                  \item  Venous thromboembolism
                  \item  Increased risk of diabetes mellitus 
                  \item  Ectopic pregnancy
                  \end{tabenum}
 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want the answers to be indented with respect to the question, replace `leftmargin=*` with `leftmargin=30pt` or a different length of your choice.

Comment: Hi, it's working, although what if my options are too long in the text? how to split them?

Comment: Which options? The individual answers/items? What does "too long in text mean" and what does "split them"  refer to? Linebreaks in long items will occur automatically while the overall width of the table will adapt to the width of the text.

Comment: Please check the edit in question.

Comment: @AadityaUra: I assume, the page only contains the table. Is that correct? You mention wanting to fit the table onto the page. Does it have to fito onto a single page or are you willing to let it occupy multiple pages?

Comment: Hi, I want to shrink the size to fit it properly in the page and yes the page contains only table.

Comment: Unless you shrik the font size quote drastically or switch to the different enumerate style I suggested in a previous comment, fitting the whole table onto a single page will be hardly possible.