# How to increase the width of the table heading row and keep the content in the centre of row?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, tabularx, alignment

```
\documentclass[11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\newcolumntype{"}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Overview of notation} \label{tab:notation_TC} \centering \resizebox{5cm}{!}{% 
        \begin{tabular}{l  l }
            %   {
            \thickhline
            
            \bf Notation & \bf Description \\ [0.75ex]
            \hline
            hey & hello\\
        
            \thickhline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about a `booktabs` based approach, such as `\documentclass[11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Overview of notation} \label{tab:notation_TC} \centering 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\bfseries Notation & \bfseries Description\\
\midrule
hey & hello\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}`?

Comment: You mention wanting to increase the width of a row, while keeping the contents in the center, but your image shows that you altered the height of the first row (and you used the "vertical-alignment" tag). Also, does "center"  refer to the vertical or horizontal center? Please clarify how the expected output should look like.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but do not use `\resizebox` on a table. This will lead to inconsistent font sizes and line widths throughout the document. Also, do not use `\bf`, but `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}?. (See also: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144))

Comment: Thanks a lot @leandriis. The booktabs option u suggested solved the problem. Related to your recent comment. What is the right way to scale down a table? For that I am using \resizebox.

Comment: Don't scale a table at all or decrease the font size by using a command such as \small.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis.

Comment: I suspect what you need is `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Notation}` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Overview of notation}
  \label{tab:notation_TC}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={ll},row{1}={m,1cm,font=\bfseries}}
    \hline[2pt]    
      Notation &  Description \\
    \hline
      Hey      & Hello \\
    \hline[2pt]
  \end{tblr}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @L.J.R. Just need a view which approach is better? I find using booktabs easier.

Comment: @mathslove You can also use `booktabs` rules by `\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}` while using `tabularray` package.

Comment: Facing problem during compilation. It is showing tabularray.sty not found

Comment: You need to update your TeX distribution first.

Comment: Updated it. Now the version in 3.1.2. Again the same problem.

Comment: But TeXlive or MikTeX doesn’t have version 3.1.2.??

Comment: I am using texstudio.

Comment: texstudio is just an editor. You need to update your texlive or miktex.

Comment: After updating MikTex the problem got resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[ht] 
\caption{Overview of notation} 
\label{tab:notation_TC} 
\centering  
% \small % uncomment for a smaller font size in the table
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
\toprule 
\bfseries Notation & \bfseries Description\\ 
\midrule 
hey & hello\\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```