# Why is there bold font across the entire document?

Tags: typography, cv

Consider this CV: https://nchlswllms.github.io/academic_cv.pdf

The .cls file:

```
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}       
\usepackage{array}                  
\usepackage{ifthen}

\pagestyle{empty}                  


% HEADINGS: Commands for printing name and address

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}}        
\def \@name {}                      

\def \addressSep {$\diamond$}         

% One or two address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax

% \address command can be used to set first and second address (optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
    \def \@addressone {#1}
  }
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}


% DOCUMENT: Create the head of the document

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document                     
  \printname                        
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{     
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{     
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
}


% SECTIONS: Create section headings

% Used to create large resume section
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1}
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule\nopagebreak
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

% Used to format job listing
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Default Layout: %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %%    Employer (bold)                     Dates (regular)    %%
  %%    Title (emphasis)                Location (emphasis)    %%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  {\bf #1}                 \hfill                  { #2}% Stop a space
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{
  \\
  {\em #3}                 \hfill                  {\em #4}% Stop a space
  }\smallskip
  % \cdot used for bullets, items non-indented
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em}
  \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}
}{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em}
}

\def\namesize{\huge}
\def\nameskip{\medskip}
\def\addressskip{\smallskip}
\def\sectionskip{\bigskip}
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip}
```

The .tex file:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} 

\usepackage{etaremune}

\name{Nicholas Williams} % Your name
\address{\texttt{https://nchlswllms.github.io} \\ \texttt{github.com/nchlswllms} \\ \texttt{williams@ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp}}
%\address{Flat 203, Titanium Point \\ 24 Palmers Road \\ London, E2 0FA \\ +44 7789 456522} % Your address


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf Doctorate in Mathematics} \hfill {\em September 2018 -- May 2022} \\
University of Cologne \hfill {\em April 2021 -- May 2022}\\
Started at University of Leicester  \hfill {\em September 2018 -- April 2021} \\
Supervisor: Sibylle Schroll \\
Thesis title: {\em Higher-dimensional combinatorics in representation theory} \\
{\em Summa cum laude}

\sectionlineskip

{\bf Graduate Diploma in Quantitative Economics} \hfill {\em October 2017 -- June 2018} \\
Birkbeck, University of London \\
Distinction

\sectionlineskip

{\bf MMathPhil in Mathematics \& Philosophy} \hfill {\em October 2012 -- June 2016} \\ 
Worcester College, Oxford \\
Double First Class Honours

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EMPLOYMENT SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Employment}

{\bf Postdoctoral Research Associate} \hfill {\em September 2022 -- March 2025} \\ 
Lancaster University \\
With David Pauksztello

\sectionlineskip

{\bf JSPS Short Term Postdoctoral Research Fellow} \hfill {\em May 2022 -- August 2022} \\ 
University of Tokyo \\
With Osamu Iyama

\sectionlineskip

{\bf Graduate Teaching Assistant} \hfill {\em September 2021 -- December 2021} \\ 
King's College London

\sectionlineskip

{\bf Guest Teacher} \hfill {\em September 2021 -- December 2021} \\ 
London School of Economics

\sectionlineskip

{\bf Feedback session leader} \hfill {\em January 2019 -- December 2020} \\ 
University of Leicester

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PUBLICATIONS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Publications}

\begin{etaremune}
\item New interpretations of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders \hfill {\em 2022}\\ 
{\em Advances in Mathematics}, Volume 407, 108552

\item The combinatorics of tensor products of higher Auslander algebras of type~$A$ \hfill {\em 2021}\\
(With Jordan McMahon)\\
{\em Glasgow Mathematical Journal}, 63(3), pp.\ 526--546.
\end{etaremune}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONFERENCE PROCEEDINGS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Conference proceedings}

\begin{etaremune}
\item The higher Stasheff--Tamari orders in representation theory \hfill {\em To appear}\\
{\em Proceedings of the 2020 International Conference on Representations of Algebras}

\item The first higher Stasheff--Tamari orders are quotients of the higher Bruhat orders \hfill {\em 2021}\\
{\em Proceedings of the 33rd International Conference on Formal Power Series and Algebraic Combinatorics, Séminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire} 85B, Art.\ 6, 12.
\end{etaremune}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PREPRINTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Preprints}

\begin{etaremune}
\item Stability spaces of string and band modules \hfill {\em 2022}\\
(With Sibylle Schroll, Aran Tattar, Hipolito Treffinger, and Yadira Valdivieso) \\
{\tt arXiv:2208.15000}

\item Triangulations of prisms and preprojective algebras of type $A$ \hfill {\em 2022}\\
(With Osamu Iyama)\\
{\tt arXiv:2208.12957}

\item Quiver combinatorics for higher-dimensional triangulations \hfill {\em 2021}\\
{\tt arXiv:2112.09189}

\item The two higher Stasheff--Tamari orders are equal \hfill {\em 2021}\\
{\tt arXiv:2106.01050}

\item The first higher Stasheff--Tamari orders are quotients of the higher Bruhat orders \hfill {\em 2020}\\
{\tt arXiv:2012.10371}
\end{etaremune}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRIZES AND SCHOLARSHIPS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Prizes and Scholarships}

{\bf Gibbs prize for Mathematics \& Philosophy} \hfill {\em 2016} \\ 
University of Oxford \\
For top performance in Mathematics papers

\smallskip

{\bf Gibbs prize for Mathematics \& Philosophy} \hfill {\em 2015} \\ 
University of Oxford \\
For top performance in Mathematics papers

\smallskip

{\bf Academic scholarship} \hfill {\em 2013} \\ 
Worcester College, Oxford

\smallskip

{\bf Honorary scholarship} \hfill {\em 2007} \\ 
Westminster School

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INVITED TALKS (IN PERSON) SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Invited conference talks (in person)}

{\bf A structural approach to maximal green sequences} \hfill {\em September 2022} \\
{\em Silting theory, algebras and representations} \\
Charles University, Prague
\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INVITED TALKS (VIRTUAL) SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Invited conference talks (virtual)}

{\bf An algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em November 2020}\\
{\em International Conference on Representations of Algebras}\\
Selected to give talk by scientific committee based on research snapshot\\
Via BigBlueButton

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTRIBUTED TALKS (IN PERSON) SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Contributed conference talks (in person)}

{\bf Algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em July 2022} \\
{\em Representation theory and various issues on related topics} \\
Research Institute for Mathematical Sciences, Kyoto University

\smallskip

{\bf Nice triangulations of cyclic polytopes} \hfill {\em June 2019} \\ 
{\em London Mathematical Society Graduate Student Meeting}

\smallskip

{\bf Higher analogues of Grassmannian clusters} \hfill {\em April 2019} \\ 
{\em Maurice Auslander Distinguished Lectures and International Conference}

\smallskip

{\bf Higher analogues of Grassmannian clusters} \hfill {\em April 2019} \\ 
{\em New Connections and Directions in Representation Theory} \\
University of Leeds

\smallskip

{\bf Higher analogues of Grassmannian clusters} \hfill {\em April 2019} \\ 
{\em Tropical Geometry meets Representation Theory} \\
University of Leicester

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTRIBUTED TALKS (VIRTUAL) SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Contributed conference talks (virtual)}

{\bf The first higher Stasheff--Tamari orders are quotients of} \hfill {\em January 2022} \\
{\bf the higher Bruhat orders}\\
{\em Formal Power Series and Algebraic Combinatorics}\\
Bar-Ilan University

\smallskip

{\bf The higher Stasheff--Tamari orders on triangulations of cyclic polytopes} \hfill {\em June 2021} \\ 
{\em London Mathematical Society Graduate Student Meeting}

\smallskip

{\bf Vertex figures of cubillages of cyclic zonotopes} \hfill {\em November 2020} \\ 
{\em London Mathematical Society Graduate Student Meeting}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SEMINAR TALKS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Seminar talks (in person)}

{\bf Mutation in higher cluster categories} \hfill {\em October 2022} \\ 
Seminar@Aarhus \\
Aarhus University

\smallskip

%{\bf Equivalence of maximal green sequences} \hfill {\em April 2022} \\ 
%Working seminar in algebra and geometry \\
%University of Cologne
%
%\smallskip

{\bf Equivalence of maximal green sequences} \hfill {\em February 2022} \\ 
Paris algebra seminar \\
Institut de Math\'ematiques de Jussieu-Paris Rive Gauche

\smallskip

%{\bf Cluster categories and crossing conditions} \hfill {\em February 2020} \\ 
%Working seminar in algebra and geometry     \\
%University of Leicester
%
%\smallskip

{\bf An algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em November 2019} \\ 
Pure mathematics seminar \\
University of East Anglia

\smallskip

%{\bf An algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em November 2019} \\ 
%Working seminar in algebra and geometry \\
%University of Leicester
%
%\smallskip
%
%{\bf Nice triangulations of cyclic polytopes} \hfill {\em October 2019} \\ 
%PhD seminar \\
%University of Leicester

\smallskip

{\bf Higher analogues of Grassmannian clusters} \hfill {\em April 2019} \\ 
Algebra and number theory seminar \\
University of Graz

%\smallskip
%
%{\bf Alternating strand diagrams, plabic graphs, and Grassmannians} \hfill {\em January 2019} \\ 
%PhD seminar \\
%University of Leicester
%
%\smallskip
%
%{\bf Grassmannians} \hfill {\em October 2018} \\ 
%Working seminar in algebra and geometry \\
%University of Leicester

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SEMINAR TALKS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Seminar talks (virtual)}

{\bf Cyclic polytopes and higher Auslander--Reiten theory III} \hfill {\em July 2022} \\ 
Tokyo--Nagoya algebra seminar \\
University of Tokyo and Nagoya University

\smallskip

{\bf Cyclic polytopes and higher Auslander--Reiten theory II} \hfill {\em June 2022} \\ 
Tokyo--Nagoya algebra seminar \\
University of Tokyo and Nagoya University

\smallskip

{\bf Mutating cluster-tilting objects in $(d + 2)$-angulated cluster categories} \hfill {\em June 2022} \\ 
FD seminar

\smallskip

{\bf Cyclic polytopes and higher Auslander--Reiten theory I} \hfill {\em June 2022} \\ 
Tokyo--Nagoya algebra seminar \\
University of Tokyo and Nagoya University

\smallskip

{\bf An algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em January 2022} \\ 
Aachen--Bochum--Cologne Darstellungstheorie Seminar\\
RWTH Aachen University, Ruhr-University Bochum, and University of Cologne

\smallskip

{\bf Cyclic polytopes and higher Auslander--Reiten theory} \hfill {\em December 2021} \\ 
Tokyo--Nagoya algebra seminar\\
University of Tokyo and Nagoya University

\smallskip

{\bf The two higher Stasheff--Tamari orders are equal} \hfill {\em May 2021} \\ 
Working seminar in algebra and geometry \\
University of Cologne

\smallskip

{\bf The higher Stasheff--Tamari orders in representation theory} \hfill {\em April 2021} \\ 
Paris algebra seminar \\
Institut de Math\'ematiques de Jussieu-Paris Rive Gauche

\smallskip

{\bf New interpretations of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em March 2021} \\ 
Diskrete Mathematik / Geometrie Forschungsseminar \\
TU Berlin

\smallskip

{\bf The Tamari lattice in representation theory} \hfill {\em March 2021} \\ 
Junior Algebra Colloquium \\
University of Bristol

\smallskip

%{\bf KP solitons} \hfill {\em October 2020} \\ 
%PhD seminar \\
%University of Leicester
%
%\smallskip
%
%{\bf KP solitons and the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders II} \hfill {\em October 2020} \\ 
%Working seminar in algebra and geometry     \\
%University of Leicester
%
%\smallskip
%
%{\bf KP solitons and the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders I} \hfill {\em September 2020} \\ 
%Working seminar in algebra and geometry     \\
%University of Leicester
%
%\smallskip
%
%{\bf Triangulations of odd-dimensional cyclic polytopes} \hfill {\em June 2020} \\ 
%PhD seminar \\
%University of Leicester
%
%\smallskip
%
%{\bf Fukaya categories and higher Auslander algebras of type $A$} \hfill {\em April 2020} \\ 
%Working seminar in algebra and geometry     \\
%University of Leicester
\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   POSTERS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Posters}

{\bf An algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em June 2021} \\ 
{\em Young Researchers in Mathematics} \\
Online \\
Winner of 1\textsuperscript{st} prize in poster competition

\smallskip

{\bf An algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em May 2021} \\ 
{\em Advances in Representation Theory of Algebras} \\
Online

\smallskip

{\bf New interpretations of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em January 2021} \\ 
{\em Combinatorial algebra meets algebraic combinatorics} \\
Universit\'e du Qu\'ebec \`a Montr\'eal \\
Online

\smallskip

{\bf An algebraic interpretation of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em November 2020} \\ 
{\em International Conference on Representations of Algebras} \\
``Research snapshot''\\
Online

\smallskip

{\bf New interpretations of the higher Stasheff--Tamari orders} \hfill {\em September 2020} \\ 
{\em Virtual Heidelberg Laureate Forum} \\
Online

\smallskip

{\bf Representation theory and Grassmannians} \hfill {\em March 2019} \\ 
{\em STEM for Britain} \\
Poster competition at UK Parliament

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GRANTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Grants}

London Mathematical Society Scheme 8 \hfill {\em April 2020} \\
Postgraduate research conference grants \\
{\em Categorifications in Representation Theory} conference organised with Aran Tattar \\
GBP 2,500

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ORGANISATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Organisation}

{\bf K\"oln Algebra and Representation Theory seminar} \hfill {\em April 2021 -- May 2022} \\
Co-organiser \\
University of Cologne \\
Online

{\bf Categorifications in Representation Theory conference} \hfill {\em September 2020} \\
Co-organised with Aran Tattar \\
Online

\smallskip

{\bf Mathematics PhD seminar} \hfill {\em September 2019 -- August 2020} \\
University of Leicester

\smallskip

{\bf Representation theory and mirror symmetry conference} \hfill {\em May 2019} \\
Local organising committee \\
University of Leicester

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESEARCH STAYS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Research stays}

University of Cologne \hfill {\em April 2021} \\
Visiting: Sibylle Schroll and Aran Tattar \\
1 week

\smallskip

University of Cambridge \hfill {\em December 2021} \\
Isaac Newton Institute for Mathematical Sciences \\
Cluster algebras and representation theory programme \\
Invited participant \\
1 week

\smallskip

University of Graz \hfill {\em April 2019} \\
Visiting: Jordan McMahon \\
Host: Karin Baur \\
1 week

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REVIEWING SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Reviewing}

AMS MathSciNet \hfill {\em October 2022 -- present}

\smallskip

zbMATH \hfill {\em September 2020 -- present} \\
5 reviews written

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFEREEING SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Refereeing}

Journal of Algebraic Combinatorics

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TEACHING SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Teaching}

{\bf Real analysis} \hfill {\em September 2021 -- December 2021} \\
Class teacher (online) \\
King's College London

\smallskip

{\bf MA107: Quantitative methods} \hfill {\em September 2021 -- December 2021} \\
Class teacher \\
London School of Economics

\smallskip

{\bf Calculus \& analysis} \hfill {\em October 2020 -- December 2020} \\
Class teacher (online) \\
University of Leicester

\smallskip

{\bf Second-year algebra} \hfill {\em January 2020 -- April 2020} \\
Class teacher \\
University of Leicester

\smallskip

{\bf Calculus \& analysis} \hfill {\em October 2019 -- April 2020} \\
Class teacher \\
University of Leicester

\smallskip

{\bf Elements of number theory} \hfill {\em October 2019 -- December 2019} \\
Class teacher \\
University of Leicester

\smallskip

{\bf Calculus \& analysis} \hfill {\em January 2019 -- March 2019} \\
Class teacher \\
University of Leicester

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMITTEE ROLES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Committee roles}

Small Grants Committee \hfill {\em September 2022 -- present} \\
The Leathersellers' Company

\smallskip

Mathematics \& Philosophy Representative \hfill {\em 2015 -- 2016} \\
Joint Consultative Committee with Undergraduates \\
University of Oxford

\smallskip

Undergraduate Representative \hfill {\em 2015 -- 2016} \\
Joint Committee for Mathematics and Philosophy \\
University of Oxford

\smallskip

Undergraduate Representative \hfill {\em 2015 -- 2016} \\
Mathematics Department Art Committee \\
University of Oxford

\end{rSection}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OUTREACH SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Outreach}

University of Leicester Representative \hfill {\em November 2018, 2019, 2020} \\
{\em Research in the UK afternoon} \\
University of Cambridge

\smallskip

Student Helper \hfill {\em March 2013, 2014, 2015} \\
{\em Oxford and Cambridge Student Conferences}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OTHER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Other}

London Mathematical Society \hfill {\em June 2019 -- present} \\
Associate member \\
3 reports on conferences written for the LMS newsletter

\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Programming & Python, Sage, Maple, node.js, Haskell \\
& Git \\
& \LaTeX
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l @{\hspace{6ex}} l}
Languages & & \\
&& (CEFR levels) \\
& English & Native \\
& German & B1 \\
& French & B1 \\
& Japanese & A2 \\
& Spanish & A1
\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}

   
   
\end{document}
```

Why is everything bold? how do we match the output as in the link? I am using the TeXworks distribution.

Comment: I recommend you edit the code in your question to show a minimal working example... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example

Comment: `\renewcommand{\document}` is a _really_ bad idea, you should only redefine core latex commands if you know it is safe. Also `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993, surprising to see it still being used here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This isn't my CV, it is a template provided by a friend. In the LaTex distribution he uses it works as desired(see attached link). However in TeXworks, everything is bold. I want to fix this to match his output.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (or at least what I think the problem is). When I try this code the titles are indeed bold (like **Graduate Teaching Assistant** or **Mathematics PhD seminar**) but that is intended I guess? Everything else is in normal font or emphasized (italics). How does the output look for you? Which version of LaTeX do you use, and which compiler?

Comment: Note that TeXworks is only an editor which does not influence the processing, the important information is listed in the first few lines of the log file.

Comment: @Marijn There isn't a log file.

Comment: wherever you got it from, it is fundamentally wrong to redefine `\document` or use `\bf`

Comment: @Math latex _always_ writes a log file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you think you can fix it? I'm a novice at LaTex.. In my directory where the tex and cls files are saved, there is no log file

Comment: use a standard class, why pick up unsupported, undocumented code. Such issues are to be expected.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I liked the layout of this CV and decided to adopt it. I do not know how to create an identical using the "standard way"

Comment: TeXworks may put the `.log` file in a different folder or delete it directly after compilation. You can switch off this behavior in the TeXworks menu, but it is probably easier to compile your document from the command line using the command `pdflatex name_of_your_file.tex`, then you can find the log file in the same folder (but also the output on the command line can tell you everything about the LaTeX version).

Comment: @Marijn How do we switch off deletion of log files through the menu?

Comment: Anyway, I just tested some versions and in TeX Live 2021 and earlier the output is ok, but in TeX Live 2022 I can reproduce the issue - so probably you also have a new version.

Comment: @Marijn Yes, I'm pretty sure it is the new version. I need to fix this urgently as I need to send my CV off for an event..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `resume` class uses deprecated font commands `\bf` and `\em`. These commands are supposed to be used inside a group, like `{\bf Doctorate in Mathematics}` in the code above, where `{ }` creates the group. This is needed because `\bf` is a switch, i.e., it changes all remaining text within scope to bold. The scope is the group, or else the rest of the document.

Environments and commands often also create a group. In `resume.cls` this behavior is used for the section titles, which contains the line `\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}`. Here `\MakeUppercase` is intended to create the group that limits the effect of `\bf` to the title only.

In June 2022 the implementation of `\MakeUppercase` has changed, and now the font setting is no longer limited to the argument of this command, but instead influences the rest of the document.

To fix this you can use the non-deprecated command `\textbf{}`, which takes an argument. This command makes sure that bold is only applied to the argument. It also has a number of other advantages (see ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text)).

In this case, change the offending line (nr. 69) in `resume.cls` to the following:

```
\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}
```

Then it shows the correct fonts with the example provided.

However, it general it is advised not to use classes that use the deprecated font commands, and also not use them in your own documents of course.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much for this :)

Comment: Even better `\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}`

Comment: why's that better, @egreg?

Comment: @marktani Conceptually better: you want to boldface uppercase, not conversely

Comment: The resume.cls which I am using, it was line no. 99 => line which formats section title.