# Some issues with title page

Tags: positioning, titles

I have a few problems whilst creating my title page.

1. How would italicize just the email, course, supervisor etc., and not the actual text itself?
2. How would I shift the `Email: <myemail>`, `Course: <course name>`, `Supervisor: <supervisor name>` etc. to the left? I tried using the `flushleft` command but it can't seem to work.
3. How would I shift the date right below my name? It does not work when I move the `\date` command below my name.

I'm trying to follow the style in this:

[image]

Currently my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}


\begin{document}

\title{\bf TitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitle}
\author{My nameMy nameMy nameMy name\\
\\
\it {Email}: \texttt{123@myemail.com}\\
\it {Course}: Course Name\\
\it {Supervisor}: Professor Name\\
\\
Department of engineering
}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're getting the italics with the wrong scope is that you are using `\it` incorrectly, since it is a switch and not a command that takes an argument.  Independently, however, you shouldn't use such commands at all, as they are deprecated and have been replaced with better commands.  See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693) for some discussion.

Here's a solution to your problem using the `titling` package, and defining a command to set the variable information in the title page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{titling} % for useful adjustments to the titles
\usepackage{url} % for simple url formatting
% command to make the course info
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myinfo}[2]{
  \gdef\@myinfo{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \textit{E-mail:} & \url{myemail@email.edu}\\
  \textit{Course:} & #2\\
  \textit{Professor:} & #1
  \end{tabular}
  \par\vspace{12pt}
  \textsc{Department of Statistics, Stanford University}}
}
% add the extra information after the date
\postdate{\par\vspace{12pt}\@myinfo\end{center}}
\makeatother

\title{\textbf{Stochastic Processes}}
\author{My Name}
\myinfo{Prof. Smith}{STAT 801} % provide course and prof info
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks Alan! Especially helpful about the pointers regarding the italic and bold text.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're trying to bend `\maketitle` in a really obscure way. I probably wouldn't go about doing this, as it seems like it's a bit more trouble than it's worth.

I'd suggest using a custom `titlepage` environment, like so:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  {\Large\bfseries My Super Awesome Thesis}\\
  %
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  %
  My Name\\
  \today\\
  %
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  %
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\itshape}rl@{}}
    Email:      & {\ttfamily your@email.com} \\
    Course:     & Course Title               \\
    Supervisor: & Professor's Name
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE renders like so:

[image: Rendering of MWE]

Obviously you can adjust and tweak it to whatever you see fit. :)

PS: The LaTeX WikiBook also has an informative and fun section on creating custom title pages. See here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `\makebox[<width>][<l|r|c>]{<text>}` to place the text in a box of the appropriate width.  The second parameter determines the alignment of `<text>` as `l`eft, `r`ight, or `c`enter.

[image]

A simple change to set the `PropertyName` be `[r]` aligned with

```
\newcommand*{\PropertyName}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{Supervisor:}][r]{#1}}
```

yields:

[image]

The place the date I used `\today` to have it here you want it, and set the `\date{}` to be empty so nothing gets printed at the bottom.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\PropertyName}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{Supervisor:}][l]{#1}}%
\newcommand*{\PropertyValue}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\textit{Professor Name:}}][l]{\textit{#1}}}%
\begin{document}

\title{\bf TitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitle}
\author{My nameMy nameMy nameMy name\\
\today\\
\\
\PropertyName{Email:} \PropertyValue{\texttt{123@myemail.com}}\\
\PropertyName{Course:} \PropertyValue{Course Name}\\
\PropertyName{Supervisor:} \PropertyValue{Professor Name}\\
\\
Department of engineering
\date{}
}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips and various ways to create what I want. :)