# Merge columns in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I would like to merge column in LaTeX. I can make that but this line is incomplete because it still open on the left. Perhaps you will not understand what I mean, but this is the code that I wrote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}    \begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
%\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.3cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
  \hline
 \bf Id Page  & \bf Politique de Partage & \bf Nombre Amis & \bf Nombre Pages qui ont reçu la pub \\
  \hline
   78 & Amis Seulement & 23&23 \\
   81&Amis Seulement&25&25\\
   65&Amis Seulement&25&25\\
   59&Amis et leurs Amis&26&51\\
   16&Tout le Monde&27&100\\
   45&Amis et leurs Amis&27&71\\
   69&Amis Seulement&27&27\\
   74&Amis Seulement&27&27\\
   99&Amis Seulement &27&27\\
   30&Amis et leurs Amis&27&64\\


   \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Moyenne des pages qui ont reçu  }

    \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bf {\caption{Publication partagée avec une page ayant un nombre minimal d'amis dans réseau 1}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, sorry. It's rather difficult to understand. May you expand a bit?

Comment: when I want that my ligne in my table is constructed with 2 column one it is merged and the other isn't merged and corresponding to my code the second column isn't closed.

Comment: Please, show some code rather than trying to explain in that way.

Comment: @boutheina: It would be really helpful if you could just make a small example document.

Answer (score 22):

Leaving out column separations `&` for columns that contain nothing doesn't always have the desired effect when you include vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
  One & Two & Three & Four \\
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{OneTwoThree} \\
  One & Two & Three & Four
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
  One & Two & Three & Four \\
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{OneTwoThree} & \\
  One & Two & Three & Four
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

As such, include a single `&` (or as many as is required, like in the last `tabular`) to add the final vertical line, "closing" the row.

---

Here is an updated view of your minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
%\usepackage[french]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering % \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
  %\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.3cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
    \hline
    \bfseries Id Page  & \bfseries Politique de Partage & \bfseries Nombre Amis & \bfseries Nombre Pages qui ont reçu la pub \\
    \hline
    78 & Amis Seulement     & 23 &  23 \\
    81 & Amis Seulement     & 25 &  25 \\
    65 & Amis Seulement     & 25 &  25 \\
    59 & Amis et leurs Amis & 26 &  51 \\
    16 & Tout le Monde      & 27 & 100\\
    45 & Amis et leurs Amis & 27 &  71 \\
    69 & Amis Seulement     & 27 &  27 \\
    74 & Amis Seulement     & 27 &  27 \\
    99 & Amis Seulement     & 27 &  27 \\
    30 & Amis et leurs Amis & 27 &  64 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Moyenne des pages qui ont re\c{c}u  } & \\ % <---- inserted &
    \hline  
  \end{tabular}
  %\end{center}
  \caption{Publication partag\'ee avec une page ayant un nombre minimal d'amis dans r\'eseau 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}​
```

Some comments regarding your table construction:

- Don't use the `center` environment (`\begin{center}`...`\end{center}`). Rather use `\centering`. See [Should I use center or centering for figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/5764) - this holds for tables as well;
- Use `\bfseries` switch or `\textbf{...}` instead of `\bf`. See [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, ...) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764);
- For **bold** formatting of captions, use the formatting options of the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption);
- You table doesn't fit within the regular text block. In the above image output of your example, the caption is set within the text margins, giving an indication of how much the table extends beyond the margins. You may consider using the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to correct for this, or modify your layout all-together.

Comment: I don't understand well what do you mean if I merge colums it doesn't be closed?

Comment: @boutheina: In your example your only merging the first 3 (of 4) columns. Ending the table row after only 3 columns (using `\\ `) leave the first column "unused", and (La)TeX therefore doesn't insert the last vertical rule. If you use `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Moyenne des pages qui ont reçu  } &` for your merged column, the final column in that row will "close" the row with a vertical rule, as specified by the original column specification (`|c|c|c|c|`).

Comment: :please I don't understand what do you mean can you please write this?