# Cell merging of a full row not working

Tags: tables

I'm referring to this [Merge columns in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53199/merge-columns-in-latex).

I simply can't find the error, here is my LaTeX code:

```
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X |X|}
     \hline
     Lorem ipsu &  dolor sit  \\ \hline
     Lorem ipsu &  dolor sit \newline amet, consetetur  \\  \hline
     Lorem ipsu &  dolor si \\ \hline
     Lorem ipsu &  dolor si  \\ \hline
     Lorem ipsu &  dolor si \\ \hline
     Lorem ipsu &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetu / consetetur sadipscing  \\ \hline
     Lorem ipsu & dolor si  - amet \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{ | X | }{
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

  Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,}  \\ \hline 

     \end{tabularx}
```

And i  get the following, with the text should fill all the box, the green box shouldn't exitst. The green box is empty space. Where is my error?

[image: Picture of the output]

If I try setting `c` instead of `X`, my cell gets so long that it's out of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I can offer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | X |}
\hline
Lorem ipsu &  dolor sit  \\ \hline
Lorem ipsu &  dolor sit \newline amet, consetetur  \\  \hline
Lorem ipsu &  dolor si \\ \hline
Lorem ipsu &  dolor si  \\ \hline
Lorem ipsu &  dolor si \\ \hline
Lorem ipsu &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetu / consetetur sadipscing  \\ \hline
Lorem ipsu & dolor si  - amet \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{ | >{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X | }
 {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
  accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
  rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
  eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
  takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

  Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,
  vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio
  dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla
  facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! it works fine, thank you so much!