# Remove spaces after a custom definition

Tags: macros, spacing

As scientific species names should be written in *italic*, I have adopted a shortcut to do this in LaTex by creating a definition in the preamble:

```
\def\GM{{\it Gadus morhua~}}
```

Then it's easy to call for `\GM is a fish`, which returns "*Gadus morhua* is a fish". Note that I have added `~` to the definition, so that I won't need to write `\GM~`. This works except, if I want to write `The fish is called \GM.`, which would return "The fish is called *Gadus morhua* ." (with a space between morhua and period). In order to maximize my lazy writing style I would like to find a way to "eat away" that space I defined earlier. I know that a negative space exists in math mode, but writing `$\GM\!$` does not lead to a right result. Is there a way adding a negative space to text mode?

Comment: Please note that the `\it`, `\bf`, etc. font macros are deprecated because
they do not use the new font selection scheme introduced with LaTeX2e.
Please use `{\itshape ..}`, `{\bfseries ..}` or `\textit{..}`, `\textbf{..}` instead.
See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)
and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)
for more information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is exactly what the `xspace` package is for. The manual says:

> »After defining \newcommand{\gb}{Great Britain\xspace}, the command \gb
>   will determine when to insert a space after itself and when not.«

Comment: Thanks! It seems not to work with `\def`, though. If I define `\def\GM{{\it Gadus morhua\xspace}}`, I'll get *Gadus morhua*is a fish without space

Comment: @Largh Don't use `\def`, first of all, nor the deprecated command `\it`. Use `\newcommand{\GM}{\textit{Gadus morhua}\xspace}` instead.

Comment: Ops, I placed it inside `\it{}`. That's why it didn't work. Thanks for help!

Comment: Well, thanks to David Carlisle and Morten Høgholm, who wrote the package!

Comment: @Largh: Also `\xspace` must be the very last thing in the macro definition in order to be able to check for a following space. Having a `}` or anything after it will make it useless.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to what's already been said, while using `xspace`, I have discovered that if a macro which contains `\xspace` as its last argument is followed by text inside `{}`, then it does not insert a space between the two. In such a situation, one has to use the macro followed by an additional `\` and then the text inside `{}`.

For instance, if I have a macro defined as -- `\newcommand{\sdst}{steady-state\xspace}` and I use it as -- `\sdst {DYNAMICS}` then the result would be `"steady-stateDYNAMICS"` *(note the absence of space)*; whereas, if I use it as -- `\sdst\xspace {DYNAMICS}` OR `\sdst\ {DYNAMICS}` then I will get the desired result as -- `"steady-state DYNAMICS"` *(note the inserted space)*. Just thought I should mention this `xspace` quirk I noticed during my use of it!

See this insightful comment by the package author [*David Carlisle*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090), regarding the ["oddities of `xspace`"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/78565).