# Problems with acronym shortcuts (package: glossaries)

Tags: spacing, macros, formatting, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package to generate a nice list of acronyms. For often used acronyms I defined some shortcuts, e.g. `\newcommand{\myshortcut}{\acrshort{myacronym}}`. The acronym `myacronym` has been defined before with `\newacronym{myacronym}{myacronym}{myacronym is a dummy acronym used in this text}`. The Problem is, when I use `\acrshort{myacronym}` everything works well, but if I use `\myshortcut`, the acronym link is generated and added to my glossary (as it should behave), but in addition to that if a space symbol follows in behind of the acronym at the position it is used in the text, this space symbol is lost!

At first I tried to workaround this problem by changing the shortcut Definition to `\newcommand{\myshortcut}{\acrshort{myshortcut}\space}`. This works but of course this will also generate an additional space when I don't want to have it in behind, e.g. at the end of a sentence.

Now my question is can I either find out if the next symbol is a space character and add it than to my shortcut definition or is there another (perhaps simplier) way to solve this problem.

Thanks to you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Have a look at the [`xspace` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace?lang=en)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56755/15925